# Maven 2 Not Running Junit 4 Tests

Tags: java, maven-2, junit4, junit3

I'm having an issue getting surefire to run Junit4 tests. This same issue was reported in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021771?sort=newest#sort-top but the solution there was to removed the offending dependency whose transitive dependency caused the inclusion of junit3. In my case the dependency is necessary. I'm trying to figure out how to exclude transitive dependencies to junit3 so it is not included in the surefire:test classpath.

Below are my pom.xml and the output from "mvn -X test". The pom.xml attempts to use the "exclusion" element, but that doesn't seem to help. Notice near the bottom where maven adds junit3 to the test classpath.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project>
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.comcast.service</groupId>
 <artifactId>LocationServiceIntTest</artifactId>
 <version>10.01</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
 <name>Location Service Integration Test</name>
 <repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>central</id>
   <url>http://pacdcntdp01.cable.comcast.com:8081/artifactory/repo</url>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </repository>
  <repository>
   <id>3rdp-releases</id>
   <url>http://pacdcntdp01.cable.comcast.com:8081/artifactory/3rdp-releases
   </url>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </repository>
  <repository>
   <id>snapshots</id>
   <url>http://pacdcntdp01.cable.comcast.com:8081/artifactory/repo</url>
   <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
   </releases>
  </repository>
 </repositories>
 <pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
   <id>central</id>
   <url>http://pacdcntdp01.cable.comcast.com:8081/artifactory/repo</url>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </pluginRepository>
  <pluginRepository>
   <id>snapshots</id>
   <url>http://pacdcntdp01.cable.comcast.com:8081/artifactory/repo</url>
   <releases>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
   </releases>
  </pluginRepository>
 </pluginRepositories>
 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <goals>
       <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
      </goals>
     </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
     <packageName>com.comcast.service</packageName>
     <wsdlFile>${basedir}/../ServiceClient/src/main/resources/LocationService.wsdl
     </wsdlFile>
     <databindingName>adb</databindingName>
     <unpackClasses>true</unpackClasses>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.5</source>
     <target>1.5</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <configuration>
     <includes>
      <include>**/*Test.java</include>
     </includes>
     <junitArtifactName>junit:junit:jar:4.4</junitArtifactName>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
 <dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.4</version>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
   <artifactId>unitils-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.1</version>
   <type>pom</type>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
   <artifactId>unitils-testng</artifactId>
   <version>3.1</version>
   <type>pom</type>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
   <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.1</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
   <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.8</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
   <artifactId>axiom-dom</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.8</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>axis</groupId>
   <artifactId>axis-wsdl4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.1</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.rampart</groupId>
   <artifactId>rampart-core</artifactId>
   <version>1.4</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.rampart</groupId>
   <artifactId>rampart</artifactId>
   <version>1.4</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.rampart</groupId>
   <artifactId>rahas</artifactId>
   <version>1.4</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
   <artifactId>geronimo-jaxws_2.1_spec</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
   <version>2.4</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
 <reporting>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </reporting>
</project>
```

---

```
+ Error stacktraces are turned on.
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 13:16:01-0600)
Java version: 1.5.0_22
Java home: c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_22\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows xp" version: "5.1" arch: "x86" Family: "windows"
[DEBUG] Building Maven user-level plugin registry from: 'C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\plugin-registry.xml'
[DEBUG] Building Maven global-level plugin registry from: 'c:\opt\apache-maven-2.2.1-bin\apache-maven-2.2.1\conf\plugin-registry.xml'
[INFO] Scanning for projects...

 ..... intentionally excluded minimizing size of post ......



[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.4.3:test' -->
[DEBUG]   (f) basedir = c:\dev\LocationService\IntegrationTest
[DEBUG]   (f) childDelegation = false
[DEBUG]   (f) classesDirectory = c:\dev\LocationService\IntegrationTest\target\classes
[DEBUG]   (f) classpathElements = [c:\dev\LocationService\IntegrationTest\target\test-classes, c:\dev\LocationService\IntegrationTest\target\classes, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.4\junit-4.4.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1\commons-logging-1.1.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.4\commons-lang-2.4.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2\commons-collections-3.2.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\ognl\ognl\2.6.9\ognl-2.6.9.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\unitils\unitils-core\3.1\unitils-core-3.1.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\testng\testng\5.8\testng-5.8-jdk15.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\axis2\axis2\1.5.1\axis2-1.5.1.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-impl\1.2.8\axiom-impl-1.2.8.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-api\1.2.8\axiom-api-1.2.8.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-activation_1.1_spec\1.0.1\geronimo-activation_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec\1.2\geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.2.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\jaxen\jaxen\1.1.1\jaxen-1.1.1.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.3.04\xml-apis-1.3.04.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\xerces\xercesImpl\2.8.1\xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec\1.0.1\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\woodstox\wstx-asl\3.2.4\wstx-asl-3.2.4.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-dom\1.2.8\axiom-dom-1.2.8.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\axis\axis-wsdl4j\1.5.1\axis-wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\rampart\rampart-core\1.4\rampart-core-1.4.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\rampart\rampart-policy\1.4\rampart-policy-1.4.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\axis2\axis2-kernel\1.4\axis2-kernel-1.4.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\servlet-api\2.3\servlet-api-2.3.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\commons-httpclient\commons-httpclient\3.1\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.3\commons-codec-1.3.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\commons-fileupload\commons-fileupload\1.2\commons-fileupload-1.2.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.0-beta1\httpcore-4.0-beta1.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore-nio\4.0-beta1\httpcore-nio-4.0-beta1.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\wsdl4j\wsdl4j\1.6.2\wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\backport-util-concurrent\backport-util-concurrent\3.1\backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\schema\XmlSchema\1.4.2\XmlSchema-1.4.2.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\neethi\neethi\2.0.4\neethi-2.0.4.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\woden\woden-api\1.0M8\woden-api-1.0M8.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\ant\ant\1.7.0\ant-1.7.0.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\ant\ant-launcher\1.7.0\ant-launcher-1.7.0.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\xerces\xmlParserAPIs\2.6.0\xmlParserAPIs-2.6.0.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\woden\woden-impl-dom\1.0M8\woden-impl-dom-1.0M8.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\annogen\annogen\0.1.0\annogen-0.1.0.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-jms_1.1_spec\1.1\geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\javax\mail\mail\1.4\mail-1.4.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\javax\activation\activation\1.1\activation-1.1.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.0\xalan-2.7.0.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\1.4\commons-io-1.4.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\axis2\axis2-codegen\1.4\axis2-codegen-1.4.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\axis2\axis2-adb\1.4\axis2-adb-1.4.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\axis2\axis2-xmlbeans\1.4\axis2-xmlbeans-1.4.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlbeans\xmlbeans\2.3.0\xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\axis2\axis2-adb-codegen\1.4\axis2-adb-codegen-1.4.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\axis2\mex\1.4\mex-1.4-impl.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\axis2\axis2-mtompolicy\1.4\axis2-mtompolicy-1.4.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\commons-discovery\commons-discovery\0.2\commons-discovery-0.2.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.15\log4j-1.2.15.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\stax\stax-api\1.0.1\stax-api-1.0.1.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\xmlbeans\xbean\2.1.0\xbean-2.1.0.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\security\wss4j\1.5.4\wss4j-1.5.4.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\santuario\xmlsec\1.4.1\xmlsec-1.4.1.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\opensaml\opensaml\1.1\opensaml-1.1.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\axis\axis-ant\1.4\axis-ant-1.4.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15\132\bcprov-jdk15-132.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\ant\ant-nodeps\1.7.0\ant-nodeps-1.7.0.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\rampart\rampart-trust\1.4\rampart-trust-1.4.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\jdom\jdom\1.0\jdom-1.0.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\xom\xom\1.0\xom-1.0.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\com\ibm\icu\icu4j\2.6.1\icu4j-2.6.1.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\rampart\rampart\1.4\rampart-1.4.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\rampart\rahas\1.4\rahas-1.4.jar, C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-jaxws_2.1_spec\1.0\geronimo-jaxws_2.1_spec-1.0.jar]
[DEBUG]   (f) disableXmlReport = false
[DEBUG]   (f) enableAssertions = true
[DEBUG]   (f) forkMode = once
[DEBUG]   (f) includes = [**/*Test.java]
[DEBUG]   (f) junitArtifactName = junit:junit
[DEBUG]   (f) localRepository = Repository[local|file://C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository]
[DEBUG]   (f) pluginArtifactMap = {org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter=org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:jar:2.4.3:runtime, org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-api=org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-api:jar:2.4.3:runtime, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils=org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.1:runtime, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api=org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6:runtime, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact=org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6:runtime, org.apache.maven:maven-project=org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6:runtime, org.apache.maven:maven-core=org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.6:runtime, org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain=org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:1.0:runtime}
[DEBUG]   (f) printSummary = true
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.mycompany.service:LocationServiceIntTest:10.01 @ c:\dev\LocationService\IntegrationTest\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) projectArtifactMap = {junit:junit=junit:junit:jar:4.4:test, org.unitils:unitils-core=org.unitils:unitils-core:jar:3.1:compile, commons-logging:commons-logging=commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1:compile, commons-lang:commons-lang=commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile, commons-collections:commons-collections=commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:compile, ognl:ognl=ognl:ognl:jar:2.6.9:compile, org.unitils:unitils-testng=org.unitils:unitils-testng:pom:3.1:compile, org.testng:testng=org.testng:testng:jar:jdk15:5.8:compile, org.apache.axis2:axis2=org.apache.axis2:axis2:jar:1.5.1:compile, org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl=org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl:jar:1.2.8:compile, org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api=org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:jar:1.2.8:compile, org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-activation_1.1_spec=org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-activation_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile, org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec=org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec:jar:1.2:compile, jaxen:jaxen=jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.1:compile, xml-apis:xml-apis=xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:compile, xerces:xercesImpl=xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.8.1:compile, org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec=org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile, org.codehaus.woodstox:wstx-asl=org.codehaus.woodstox:wstx-asl:jar:3.2.4:compile, org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom=org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom:jar:1.2.8:compile, axis:axis-wsdl4j=axis:axis-wsdl4j:jar:1.5.1:compile, org.apache.rampart:rampart-core=org.apache.rampart:rampart-core:jar:1.4:compile, org.apache.rampart:rampart-policy=org.apache.rampart:rampart-policy:jar:1.4:compile, org.apache.axis2:axis2-kernel=org.apache.axis2:axis2-kernel:jar:1.4:compile, javax.servlet:servlet-api=javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.3:compile, commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient=commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile, commons-codec:commons-codec=commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3:compile, commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload=commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2:compile, org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore=org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.0-beta1:compile, org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio=org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:jar:4.0-beta1:compile, wsdl4j:wsdl4j=wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.2:compile, backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent=backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1:compile, org.apache.ws.commons.schema:XmlSchema=org.apache.ws.commons.schema:XmlSchema:jar:1.4.2:compile, org.apache.neethi:neethi=org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:2.0.4:compile, org.apache.woden:woden-api=org.apache.woden:woden-api:jar:1.0M8:compile, org.apache.ant:ant=org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.7.0:compile, org.apache.ant:ant-launcher=org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.7.0:compile, xerces:xmlParserAPIs=xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.0:compile, org.apache.woden:woden-impl-dom=org.apache.woden:woden-impl-dom:jar:1.0M8:compile, annogen:annogen=annogen:annogen:jar:0.1.0:compile, org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec=org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1:compile, javax.mail:mail=javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4:compile, javax.activation:activation=javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile, xalan:xalan=xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.0:compile, commons-io:commons-io=commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4:compile, org.apache.axis2:axis2-codegen=org.apache.axis2:axis2-codegen:jar:1.4:compile, org.apache.axis2:axis2-adb=org.apache.axis2:axis2-adb:jar:1.4:compile, org.apache.axis2:axis2-xmlbeans=org.apache.axis2:axis2-xmlbeans:jar:1.4:compile, org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans=org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.3.0:compile, org.apache.axis2:axis2-adb-codegen=org.apache.axis2:axis2-adb-codegen:jar:1.4:compile, org.apache.axis2:mex=org.apache.axis2:mex:jar:impl:1.4:compile, org.apache.axis2:axis2-mtompolicy=org.apache.axis2:axis2-mtompolicy:jar:1.4:compile, commons-discovery:commons-discovery=commons-discovery:commons-discovery:jar:0.2:compile, log4j:log4j=log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15:compile, stax:stax-api=stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile, xmlbeans:xbean=xmlbeans:xbean:jar:2.1.0:compile, org.apache.ws.security:wss4j=org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:jar:1.5.4:compile, org.apache.santuario:xmlsec=org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:1.4.1:compile, opensaml:opensaml=opensaml:opensaml:jar:1.1:compile, org.apache.axis:axis-ant=org.apache.axis:axis-ant:jar:1.4:compile, bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15=bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15:jar:132:compile, org.apache.ant:ant-nodeps=org.apache.ant:ant-nodeps:jar:1.7.0:compile, org.apache.axis2:addressing=org.apache.axis2:addressing:mar:1.4:compile, org.apache.rampart:rampart-trust=org.apache.rampart:rampart-trust:jar:1.4:compile, dom4j:dom4j=dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile, jdom:jdom=jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile, xom:xom=xom:xom:jar:1.0:compile, com.ibm.icu:icu4j=com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:2.6.1:compile, org.apache.rampart:rampart=org.apache.rampart:rampart:jar:1.4:compile, org.apache.rampart:rahas=org.apache.rampart:rahas:jar:1.4:compile, org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jaxws_2.1_spec=org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jaxws_2.1_spec:jar:1.0:compile}
[DEBUG]   (f) redirectTestOutputToFile = false
[DEBUG]   (f) remoteRepositories = [Repository[central|http://pacdcntdp01.cable.mycompany.com:8081/artifactory/repo], Repository[snapshots|http://pacdcntdp01.cable.mycompany.com:8081/artifactory/repo]]
[DEBUG]   (f) reportFormat = brief
[DEBUG]   (f) reportsDirectory = c:\dev\LocationService\IntegrationTest\target\surefire-reports
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@90288e
[DEBUG]   (f) testClassesDirectory = c:\dev\LocationService\IntegrationTest\target\test-classes
[DEBUG]   (f) testNGArtifactName = org.testng:testng
[DEBUG]   (f) testSourceDirectory = c:\dev\LocationService\IntegrationTest\src\test\java
[DEBUG]   (f) trimStackTrace = true
[DEBUG]   (f) useFile = true
[DEBUG]   (f) useManifestOnlyJar = true
[DEBUG]   (f) workingDirectory = c:\dev\LocationService\IntegrationTest
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] [surefire:test {execution: default-test}]
[DEBUG] dummy:dummy:jar:1.0 (selected for null)
[DEBUG]   org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:jar:2.4.3:runtime (selected for runtime)
[DEBUG]     org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-api:jar:2.4.3:runtime (selected for runtime)
[DEBUG] Adding to surefire booter test classpath: C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\surefire\surefire-booter\2.4.3\surefire-booter-2.4.3.jar
[DEBUG] Adding to surefire booter test classpath: C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\surefire\surefire-api\2.4.3\surefire-api-2.4.3.jar
[DEBUG] dummy:dummy:jar:1.0 (selected for null)
[DEBUG]   org.testng:testng:jar:jdk15:5.8:compile (selected for compile)
[DEBUG] Adding to surefire booter test classpath: C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\testng\testng\5.8\testng-5.8-jdk15.jar
[DEBUG] dummy:dummy:jar:1.0 (selected for null)
[DEBUG] Retrieving parent-POM: org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-providers:pom:2.4.3 for project: null:surefire-testng:jar:null from the repository.
[DEBUG] Adding managed dependencies for unknown:surefire-testng
[DEBUG]   org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-api:jar:2.4.3
[DEBUG]   org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:jar:2.4.3
[DEBUG]   org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.1
[DEBUG]   org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-testng:jar:2.4.3:test (selected for test)
[DEBUG]     org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0:test (selected for test)
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.0.4:test (selected for test)
[DEBUG]     junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test (selected for test)
[DEBUG]     org.testng:testng:jar:jdk15:5.7:test (selected for test)
[DEBUG]     org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-api:jar:2.4.3:test (selected for test)
[DEBUG] Adding to surefire test classpath: C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\surefire\surefire-testng\2.4.3\surefire-testng-2.4.3.jar
[DEBUG] Adding to surefire test classpath: C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-artifact\2.0\maven-artifact-2.0.jar
[DEBUG] Adding to surefire test classpath: C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-utils\1.0.4\plexus-utils-1.0.4.jar
[DEBUG] Adding to surefire test classpath: C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\junit\junit\3.8.1\junit-3.8.1.jar
[DEBUG] Adding to surefire test classpath: C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\surefire\surefire-api\2.4.3\surefire-api-2.4.3.jar
[DEBUG] Test Classpath :
[DEBUG]   c:\dev\LocationService\IntegrationTest\target\test-classes
[DEBUG]   c:\dev\LocationService\IntegrationTest\target\classes
[DEBUG]   C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.4\junit-4.4.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1\commons-logging-1.1.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.4\commons-lang-2.4.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2\commons-collections-3.2.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\ognl\ognl\2.6.9\ognl-2.6.9.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\unitils\unitils-core\3.1\unitils-core-3.1.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\testng\testng\5.8\testng-5.8-jdk15.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\axis2\axis2\1.5.1\axis2-1.5.1.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-impl\1.2.8\axiom-impl-1.2.8.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-api\1.2.8\axiom-api-1.2.8.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-activation_1.1_spec\1.0.1\geronimo-activation_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec\1.2\geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.2.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\jaxen\jaxen\1.1.1\jaxen-1.1.1.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.3.04\xml-apis-1.3.04.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\xerces\xercesImpl\2.8.1\xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec\1.0.1\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\woodstox\wstx-asl\3.2.4\wstx-asl-3.2.4.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-dom\1.2.8\axiom-dom-1.2.8.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\axis\axis-wsdl4j\1.5.1\axis-wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\rampart\rampart-core\1.4\rampart-core-1.4.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\rampart\rampart-policy\1.4\rampart-policy-1.4.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\axis2\axis2-kernel\1.4\axis2-kernel-1.4.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\servlet-api\2.3\servlet-api-2.3.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\commons-httpclient\commons-httpclient\3.1\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.3\commons-codec-1.3.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\commons-fileupload\commons-fileupload\1.2\commons-fileupload-1.2.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.0-beta1\httpcore-4.0-beta1.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore-nio\4.0-beta1\httpcore-nio-4.0-beta1.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Documents and Settings\swall2633c\.m2\repo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how exactly you could get the JUnit 4 running with all of your dependencies, but I did notice that you're dependency on the TestNG Unitils artifact was what was causing the problem.

Note that in order to get my test working, I had to remove the repositories, the plugins other than the compiler and surefire, and the apache rampart dependencies.

The three changes I made in order to get a sample JUnit 4 test case running were:

- Remove the junitArtifactName element from the surefire configuration
- Moved the junit artifact from the dependencyManagement section to the dependency section
- Remove the unitils-testng artifact from the dependencies.  You have it listed as a having a type of pom, which makes even less sense.

Note that the unitils-core is also of type pom, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: deterb, Thanks so much for your insight. Implementing your suggestion did indeed correct the issue. I was mistaken thinking unitils-testng was required. Removing it was the key to getting things working. The first two bullet points were just my attempt at trying different things to get it working. I also removed the pom type from the unitils-core which as you pointed out didn't make sense. Thanks again!