# Maven/Surefire finds no tests to run

Tags: java, maven-2, junit, surefire

As far as I can tell, the test files location is correct.

When I run "mvn test", it finds four classes named SomethingTest (they are located in the 'test' folder).

However, it ignores any of the jUnit tests (jUnit 4, annotated with @Test).

How do I debug this?

**Edit** - this is probablly related to wrong version of jUnit being included. I see this when running "mvn -X"

```
[DEBUG] Retrieving parent-POM: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus:pom:1.0.4 for project: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-containers:pom:1.0.3 from the repository.
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:runtime (selected for runtime)
[DEBUG]         junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:runtime (selected for runtime)
[DEBUG]         org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.0.4:runtime (removed - nearer found: 1.4.1)
[DEBUG]         classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2:runtime (selected for runtime)
```

Even though my first dependency in the root pom is on jUnit 4.8.1, for some reason jUnit 3.8.1 is being included.

**Edit 2** - ok, this doesn't seem to be the answer. The Test Classpath includes the correct jUnit (4) and my test classes.

**Edit 3** - I had the test classes named SomethingTester. When I changed it to SomethingTest, it worked. I checked the include patterns for Surefire, and indeed it wasn't configured to catch Something Tester. Doh.

Comment: This seems very strange. Could you post your pom.xml?

Comment: @seanizer - did you see Edit 3? My patterns for detecting tests were simply not configured correctly.

Comment: oh I see, then you should add that as answer and accept it

Comment: @seanizer - I added this as an answer, I can't accept it yet (I hate this fact - I have to wait 2 days).

Comment: I found good answer for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178583/maven-does-not-find-junit-tests-to-run

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this is the issue:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021771?sort=newest#sort-top

mvn -X would print a bunch of these, so you can try to figure out if it's something from the above - like not using the right JUnit version (e.g. when you create from the quickstart artifact, I think the default is 3.8.1), having TestNG in the classpath before JUnit or so.

Edit: I just tried this in a simple project and the class given in the above link and it worked fine. I used junit version 4.8, that is the only dependency in my project. Just to confirm, you are annotating test methods with @org.junit.Test and there are some org.junit.Assert.assertXXX statements in these methods, correct?

Edit 2: To change junit to some other version, use this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.8</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Edit 3: You should have something like this in the test classpath:

```
[DEBUG] Test Classpath :
[DEBUG]   /home/icyrock/java/prb/target/test-classes
[DEBUG]   /home/icyrock/java/prb/target/classes
[DEBUG]   /home/icyrock/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.8/junit-4.8.jar
[DEBUG]   /home/icyrock/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.1/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
[DEBUG]   /home/icyrock/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.1/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
[DEBUG]   /home/icyrock/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar
```

Edit 4: OK, I just created a test project with maven quickstart artifact, added two modules (also created with quickstart artifact) inside, added source/target Java version and junit:junit:4.8 dependency to the parent pom only. I changed only one of the tests to JUnit4 (the other one is by default JUnit3, that's what quickstart generates), `mvn clean test` from parent folder worked just fine.

This is most likely a project setup issue - can you check your project is wired correctly (i.e. modules point to the parent, the group/artifact/versions of parent/child projects are correct). The only other thing that comes to my mind is cleaning your maven repository (at least org/apache/maven), but I doubt that would help.

It might be wise to test out on a simpler project.

Comment: mvn -X shows older jUnit versions, however it is not my poms that includes them. How do I remove it?

Comment: Just add junit:junit:4.8 as a dependency - i.e. as if you wanted that version. I edited the post.

Comment: Retrieving is OK, what does it say in "Test Classpath" section just above "T E S T S" line? I will edit to specify what it should if configured OK.

Comment: Btw, what do you mean by "root pom"? Is that the pom of the project in question or some other pom?

Comment: The classpath seems right. It includes both the test and src classes, and junit 4.8.1 jar. Still, under "T E S T S", it says "There are no tests to run"

Comment: I setup one common pom, and another pom per module that uses the first one as a parent.

Comment: To confirm, your test classes are in `src/test/java` folder? Can you check there are .class files in `target/test-classes`?

Comment: Test classes are in 'test' dir, but I have configured testSourceDirectory accordingly. There are .class files in target/test-classes.

Answer (score 4):

To finish icyrock.com's question. If there aren't any test classes compiled to target/test-classes then check your pom file and ensure that the packaging isn't 'pom'.

Answer (score 1):

Check pout if your current version of JUnit is still available in the Maven repository, otherwise, it would fail

The current version @time of this answer is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```