# Surefire doesn't launch test in src/main/java

Tags: unit-testing, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I needed to move some src/test/java to src/main/java according to this recommandation from maven-jar-plugin documentation => http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html

I did so because, i used tests (helper) classes in another projects in test scope.

So i create my-project-test, moved in test classes, and configured surefire to specify test classes directory =>

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}\src\main\java\</testSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But when i launched mvn test, 0 tests is executed =>

```
Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

The problem is the same as this one => [Maven does not find JUnit tests to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178583/maven-does-not-find-junit-tests-to-run) but the solution (configure surefire maven plugin) is not working for me.

Comment: Are you trying to run integration tests ? Furthermore why are you defining the testSourceDirectory ? And why are you using back-slashes ?

Comment: As @khmarbaise mentioned, maybe it comes from the backslashes.

Comment: I tried ${basedir}/src/main/java/  or src/main/java/ but it's the same  Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The good configuration for maven surefire plugin is =>

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</testSourceDirectory>
                    <testClassesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/</testClassesDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

Results :

Tests run: 20, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Comment: Although this will work, it is by no means a good configuration, as it does not follow the Maven way of doing things.

Sources should be in `src/main/java`. Their compiled classes will be in `target/classes`.
Test sources should be in `src/test/java`. Their compiled classes will be in `target/test-classes`.
This is the correct convention and this way Surefire will work out of the box. Putting your tests in the same directory as your module's sources is simply not right.

Comment: I didn't put tests classes in the same directory, i created anoter project suffixed by "-tests". That's the recommandation of maven-jar-plugin help => http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html  => "How to create a jar containing test classes" =>  "The preferred way"

Comment: Thanks - this helped me a lot. I am developing a set of koans that are (initially) failing unit tests but are in src/main (the already completed koans are in the src/test dir), so I needed to be able to invoke the surefire JUnit plugin on the code in src/main.  Thanks a lot for this help.

Comment: This should work for maven-failsafe-plugin, too. That's what I needed this for! Thanks, @Antoine!

Answer (score 1):

Since the test classes have now been placed in `src/main/java`, it is likely that they are getting compiled during the *compile* phase to `target/classes`.

So, though surefire is configured to indicate that the test source location is `src/main/java`, it would still look for test classes in `target/test-classes`, since this is the default location for test classes.

You could try specify [testClassesDirectory](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#testClassesDirectory) parameter suitably and see if it works.

<strike>Also, I think you may have misinterpreted the recommendation in the maven jar plugin documentation.  I do not believe they suggest moving test sources to `src/main/java`.</strike>

Comment: OK i will try so. But the maven jar plugin recommandation seams clear : "Move the sources files from src/test/java you want to share from the original project to the src/main/java of this project. The same type of movement counts for the resources as well of course."

Comment: @Antoine. You are correct.  I was familiar with `the easy way`, but never realized `the preferred way`.  I'll update the answer as well.