# Is it at all possible to execute 'mvn test' when tests are in src/main/java and not in src/test/java

Tags: maven, junit

I have inherited a project which has over 100 Junit test classes. The problem is the unit test sources  and main source files are in the same folder.There is no src/test/java folder.This can be built with ant, but with maven I am not able to get maven run the tests unless I refactor every test in to src/test folder. Is there a way to specify the a directory other than src/test/java from where mvn can run the tests?

Comment: You simply need to move the unit tests to the `src/test/java` folder you can use the same package names etc.

Comment: Answer to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986915/surefire-doesnt-launch-test-in-src-main-java

Comment: Probably written using Eclipse that treated the two the same.

Answer (score 1):

Move the tests into `src/test`. If you've inherited the project then it's time to fix mistakes.

From `src/test`, generate a list of test classes. If there's a naming convention:

```
find . -name 'Test*.java' -or -name '*Test.java' >../test-classes
```

If they're all using JUnit:

```
fgrep -lR 'junit.' >../test-classes
```

Then move those files into `src/test` by scripting your scm.