# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) on project MavenSelenium: There are test failures

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using **selenium java webdriver with maven** setup.

My **maven** reports are worked fine till now.. Suddenly it stopped working.

**And it is saying as**

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test
>   (default-test) on project DARTMavenSelenium: There are test failures.

What is the problem ?

Does any one faced this type of problem ?

Thanks

Comment: At the risk of pointing out the obvious, it's because there are tests which are failing.  If you scroll up in your maven output, you should see a list of failing tests.

Comment: Thanks you Aurand..I will check and update you..details..

Comment: Hi have changed code.. from driver.close() to driver.quit()... since before firfox window is not closing.. if I use driver.quit() window is closing... But in target\surefire reports folder I am able to see only xml reports... If I use mvn test before it use to generate html reports as well under target\surefire

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170860/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-surefire-plugin2-10test)