# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.5-r682619-maestro-2.0.0:test (default-test) on project

Tags: eclipse, maven

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.5-r682619-maestro-2.0.0:test (default-test) on project ms61-webservice-xxxx: There are test failures.  what does it mean and how to resolve it. I am doing maven build for the first time.

Comment: I had a similar problem, my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41666587/2230045

Answer (score 0):

It means the build failed because you have failing tests. Resolve it by fixing the code so the tests pass.

Comment: or use `skip test` http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html