# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.13:test (default-test) on project tcw-fip-mbp:

Tags: maven

I am getting following error while running mvn test on project

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.13:test
> (default-test) on project tcw-fip-mbp: There are test failures.
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] Please refer to
> C:\Project\workspace\RegRep2\TCW\MBP\target\surefire-reports for the
> individual test results. [ERROR]
>
> -> [Help 1] [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] To see
> the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible
> solutions, please read the following articles:

Comment: I had a similar problem, my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41666587/2230045

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Please refer to C:\Project\workspace\RegRep2\TCW\MBP\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.` 
This directory contains the output per test and all the results. That should be the start of your quest to make the tests succeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve it by adding plugin into you **pom.xml** file

```
 <plugin>  
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>  
    <version>2.22.2</version>  
    <configuration>  
      <skipTests>true</skipTests>  
    </configuration>  
 </plugin>
```

Comment: By doing this, you are telling the program to ignore the test.