# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test (default-test) on project

Tags: maven, maven-2

I have been trying from a couple of days to resolve the following error but I am unable to resolve it :(

My module's pom.xml file is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>junitcategorizer</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.topdesk.test.junitcategorizer</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>..</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>junitcategorizer.instrument</artifactId>
    <name>JUnitCategorizer InstrumentationAgent</name>
    <description>The agent used to instrument the called Java classes</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-commons</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Premain-Class>com.topdesk.junitcategorizer.instrument.InstrumentationAgent</Premain-Class>
                            <Agent-Class>com.topdesk.junitcategorizer.instrument.InstrumentationAgent</Agent-Class>
                            <Can-Redefine-Classes>true</Can-Redefine-Classes>
                            <Can-Retransform-Classes>true</Can-Retransform-Classes>
                            <Boot-Class-Path>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</Boot-Class-Path>
                            <Can-Set-Native-Method-Prefix>true</Can-Set-Native-Method-Prefix>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>org.ow2.asm:*</include>
                                </includes>
                            </artifactSet>
                            <relocations>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>org.objectweb.asm</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>org.shaded.asm</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                            </relocations>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.
12:test (default-test) on project junitcategorizer.instrument: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to D:\Masters\thesis related papers and tools\junitcategorizer\junitcategorizer.instrument\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test (default-test) on project junitcategorizer.instrument: There are test failures.

Please refer to D:\Masters\thesis related papers and tools\junitcategorizer\junitcategorizer.instrument\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: There are test failures.

    Please refer to D:\Masters\thesis related papers and tools\junitcategorizer\junitcategorizer.instrument\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.reportExecution(SurefireHelper.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.writeSummary(SurefirePlugin.java:673)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.handleSummary(SurefirePlugin.java:647)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:98)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

I tried the following but did not help:

1. mvn dependency::tree
2. mvn clean install -U or Right-click on "project" Go to "Maven" >> "Update"

Please help me!

Comment: I had a similar problem, my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41666587/2230045

Comment: Check for conflicting dependencies and remove them. It worked for me when I removed the JPA dependency. Since Spring boot comes with JPA in-built, I removed the external dependency I had. Hope it work! :)

Comment: make sure no test cases are failing

Comment: The OP was using version 2.12 which was already 4 years at that time. Since then, the Maven Surefire Plugin has even more newer versions.  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin

Answer (score 111):

This solved my issue.
It was 2.10 in my POM, just updated to 2.19.1 and refresh the POM

Add to your pom :

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

In your error code he didn't find `surefire plugin` so add it

Comment: Thanks for your response! but that did not help me as this pom file is of the module and the parent pom file does has that plugin.

Comment: That is not the problem!

Comment: <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.19.1</version>
   <configuration>
      <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
   </configuration>
  </plugin>

Comment: In my case I had to go back from 2.22.2 to 2.22.1 (I still do not understand why but it works :S )

Comment: This didn't work for me. **Environment:** Oracle Java 17 LTS; Windows 10; Maven 3.8.2 Tried to build pentaho kettle.

Comment: a hint about why this might be happening [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55250904/upgrading-maven-surefire-plugin-from-2-19-1-to-2-22-1-causes-tests-to-not-run) - as they comment there, surefire started to require JUnit 5 from 2.22.0 onwards

Answer (score 44):

This is what solves the problem:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

from [Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170860/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-surefire-plugin2-10test/41666587#41666587)

Answer (score 31):

This happens when Maven tries to run your test cases while building the jar. You can simply skip running the test cases by adding `-DskipTests` at the end of your maven command.

Ex: `mvn clean install -DskipTests`
or
`mvn clean package -DskipTests`

Comment: It's a good solution for certain cases but it seems that we need a different answer when we need a unit test. Can I get some advice?

Comment: complete java novice wants to know if after I run the `mvn clean package -DskipTests` (and my supposed jar is built now) is there another command i can follow-up with to run the tests post build?

Answer (score 12):

Was facing the same issue multiple times and I have 2 solutions:

**Solution 1:** 
Add surefire plugin reference to pom.xml. Watch that you have all nodes! 
In my IDEs auto import version was missing!!!

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

**Solution 2:** My IDE added wrong import to the start of the file.

IDE added

```
import org.junit.Test;
```

I had to replace it with

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me after upgrading the maven-surefire-plugin.

Answer (score 8):

Try this it works!

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                    <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <shutdown>kill</shutdown> <!-- Use it if required-->
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

Comment: <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
Setting this to true is just ignoring the failures, not helping failures to stop

Answer (score 7):

This is a kind of test failure.**@SpringBootApplication** annotation contains these configurations.

> 1) @Configuration
>
> 2) @ComponentScan
>
> 3) @EnableAutoConfiguration

**@EnableAutoConfiguration** is the reason for this error. This will try to automatically configure application according to dependencies in your pom.xml

As a example when you have spring-data-jpa dependency in pom it will try to add configuration to application by looking at application.properties file for data source. So you need add data source to solve that.

For MySQL :

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/lahiru
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
```

Or

You could hide this by skipping testing.

```
mvn install -DskipTests
```

For more [details](http://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-surefire-plugin-2.12.4/examples/skipping-test.html).

Answer (score 7):

It worked for me with version 3.0.0-M1.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
</plugin>
```

You might need to run it with sudo.

Answer (score 3):

I get exactly the same stacktrace when tests fail.
More to the top you should see messages identfying the failing test classes.
Or go to

```
D:\Masters\thesis related papers and tools\junitcategorizer\junitcategorizer.instrument\target\surefire-reports
```

and have a look at the failure reports.
Fix the problems and your build is ok.

Good news : Your poms seem to be ok, Maven can compile and execute tests.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the simplest way to resolve this error:

1) Go to your pom.xml file path

2) And edit the pom.xml like:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12</version>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

3) Save the file
That's it.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem and try almost all these suggestions and another options but nothing works for my case.

So I had run verbose command:  (`mvn install -X`) and saw the problem with Jacoco lib, and finally found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65435883/7925575) that works for me.

Change the Jacoco lib version in my pom file.

```
<groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
     <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>0.8.4</version>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your test files. You must clear all test files error on your project and try Clean and build.

Comment: The point of tests is NOT that they hinder you on building your project...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ubantu then try to run MVN with sudo.
I got same error for

```
mvn -Dtest=PerfLatency#latencyTest test -X
```

But

```
sudo mvn -Dtest=PerfLatency#latencyTest test -X
```

Solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the name of the class created in the package is something like somethingTest.java
Maven only picks the java files ending with Test notation.

I was getting the same error and resolving the names of all my classes by adding 'Test' at the end made it work.

Answer (score 2):

If you **skip** tests by command or Intellij maven tool it will work, but its not solution. As solution simply add following plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.0</version>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and how i resolved see below steps or Image:

1. Clicked on Windows menu item of eclipse
2. Clicked on preferences
3. select Installed JREs
4. Add your installed jdk's path(JRE home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre`)
5. Add JRE name: jdk1.8.0_201
6. Clicked on Finish
7. Apply changes and close

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k09mG.png)

Answer (score 1):

Change the version number to 2.19.1 works for me :)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
         <xmlOutputDir>${project.build.directory}/surefire</xmlOutputDir>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>`
```

Answer (score 1):

after a few days of wondering, my solution was that I forgot to use @Test annotation before the @BeforeEach

Answer (score 1):

My situation might be a bit different - but I was using Java 11 instead of Java 8.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. My default SDK was Java 11, and my project was on Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

If you're hitting this issue in Eclipse, you can try right click the project > Run as > Maven Install
For any missing plugin, add it to your pom.xml file under the plugins section and Run Maven Install again. I hope it helps.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same kind of issue, your version numbers in the dependency of Selenium, TestNG, Junit should the same that you have used in your project. For example, in your project you are using the Selenium version 3.8. This version number should be mentioned in the dependency.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0-beta1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.12</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>                
          <groupId>org.testng</groupId>                             
          <artifactId>testng</artifactId>                               
          <version>6.8</version>                                
          <scope>test</scope>                                       
        </dependency>   
      </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

3 years already, but the same thing happened to me and I wanted to contribute with my case. Using the @nikk solution I got better results, but other errors still appeared, although yes, I was allowed to package.

However, my task was to implement the code of a co-worker on the server and it did not happen to him in his test environment, so I decided to investigate a little more since the code was functional and did not correspond to me touching anything .

In the end it turned out that his application inserted mysql tables into a database that did not exist. The solution was as easy as creating such a database and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be related to the already busy port. Surefire run on 5005 port. So you need to make sure that this port is free. If not change it or kill the process. This happens in Intellij some time.

Answer (score 0):

This error is brought up for many different reasons so everyone has a different solution. However, your own webapp should hold the answer for it.

You can look it up in

> /module_with_failure/target/surefire-reports/*.txt

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to set the surefire-plugin version in the parent pom, otherwise including it as a dependency will override any configuration (includes file patterns etc) that may be inherited, e.g. from Spring Boots spring-boot-starter-test pom using pluginManagement

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

*I just adjust the cucumber version, because I had a JUnit dependency in a low version compared with the other version of cucumber in my pom file.*

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
                <version>6.9.0</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-picocontainer -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
                <version>6.9.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
                <version>6.9.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and try all the method mentioned above. Then I identified that the problem is in the pom file.

so if you have given
TestNG.xml
in your pom file. Then, Perhaps the location of the TestNG.xml file is not correct.

By writing above command it will search the file in the root directory. If your TestNG.xml file is present somewhere else other then root directory then give that path or else copy the whole path of the TestNG.xml file from the server and paste it.

In my case I have done like below:
/home/ubuntu/TestNG.xml

and the problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Karate is case sensitive so making sure your file and folder name and also package reference in Test runner file.

Answer (score 0):

After trying for some time I was able to fix the issue so thought of posting as it can be helpful to someone in the future:

1. It has nothing to do with your `pom.xml` file and does not require any additional library or plugins.
2. You are getting the path of the file where failing reports are present. Something like this:

```
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/{username}/{folderPath}/{projectName}/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
```

3. Click on that path and go to the folder. Within the folder search for the file `testing-failed.xml` file and open it in any of the editors.
4. You will be able to see the `Class/Test` which is failing. Something like this:

```
<class name="PackageName.ClassName">
```

5. Go to that file in your IDE and try to run it. If it's failing then fix it and try to run the `mvn clean install` again.

This should fix the issue, at least for me it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error yesterday:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) on project my-working-tests: There are test failures.
```

The error was solved by implementing the following two steps:

1. adding the 2.22.1 to the pom.xml fie.
2. run command `mvn -o test`

In the step step, the errored test got past, but my terminal threw error, `Could not resolve dependencies`, for the next test. That made sense because the command, `mvn -o test`, was doing the test offline, without downloading dependencies. Please note that if you do not have a next test, you will not meet the same new error as I met.

Then, I rerun the command mvn install again. It ran successfully.

Please check the code for the step 1

Old code (raised the error):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
           .......
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Updated code (solved the error):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
    <configuration>
           .......
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Hope it helps to your error.

Answer (score -1):

HI All can you try adding the below in your POM and then use 
`mvn clean compile` and then `mvn install`.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add those below line in pom.xml file on the top of `<modelversion>` tag:

```xml
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>central</id>
    <name>Central Repository</name>
    <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score -1):

surefire plugins version might be one of the reasons. For me following dependency worked. Please try:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is not in your dependencies....
you should open detail error on this path

> Please refer to D:\Masters\thesis related papers and
>   tools\junitcategorizer\junitcategorizer.instrument\target\surefire-reports
>   for the individual test results.

the detail error's in there, maybe your service class or serviceImpl class or something missing like @anotation or else...
i got error same with you,...u should try

Answer (score -1):

I experienced the same and it turned out that the surefire will do the test, I understand why skipping the test will fix the issue but in my case, the database test failed to connect. after fixing the connection, the build process is a success.

Answer (score -2):

That worked for me,

Right Click on project -> "Run as Maven Test". This will automatically download the missing plugins and than Right Click on project ->"Update Maven project" it removes the error.

Answer (score -6):

If there are test failures just skip them with

```
mvn install -DskipTests
```

but i strongly recomend fixing your test first.

Answer (score -7):

try in cmd: `mvn clean install -Dskiptests=true`

that'll skip all unit test. Might be It'll work fine for you.

Comment: That didn't change anything for me.

Comment: skipping tests isn't a solution.