# Not able to execute testng file from Maven Project . Exception on Maven Surefire plugin

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, testng-eclipse

I have created Maven project for testing one of my web application. I wanted to execute my project based on few parameters. So I added few parameters to my POM.XML and passed those properties as input to my plugins.

During execution of my maven project, I am getting below error for last two days 
**[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20:test (default-test) on project Sanity: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]**

I even referred the earlier stack over flow link   to resolve this error.[[Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test (default-test) on project.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427868/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-surefire-plugin2-12test][1])

But none of the solutions helped me to resolve the issue. I tried most of the solutions suggested

```
1) Tried cleaning project
2) updated my maven project and dependencies. 
3) Ran in debug mode also
4) Recreated my maven project also
```

Please share your suggestions to resolve this issue

Also, I am posting my POM.XML file from Build tag remvoing dependecy plugins, Test Ng file, Java file used for invoking

```
     - POM.XML


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <!-- This configuration need to be modified for the environment to be run and type of test to be executed -->
        <test>Web</test>
        <!-- Sanity, Regression -->
        <testtype>Sanity</testtype>
        <sanitysuiteFile>Sanity.xml</sanitysuiteFile>
        <regressionsuiteFile>Regression.xml</regressionsuiteFile>
    </properties>


    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.20</version>
        <configuration>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>${sanitysuiteFile}</suiteXmlFile>
            </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>

     - TestNg.XML
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <suite name="Suite">
      <test name="Test">
       <parameter name="selenium.env" value="UAT" />
      <parameter name="selenium.browser" value="IE" />
      <parameter name="selenium.pbrowser" value="Mozilla" /> 
        <classes>
          <class name="test.SanityTest"/>
        </classes>
      </test> <!-- Test -->
    </suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Below error received when ran the project in debug mode

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20:test (default-test) on project Sanity: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20:test (default-test) on project Sanity: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.reportExecution(SurefireHelper.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.handleSummary(SurefirePlugin.java:334)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:937)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:785)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
[ERROR]
```

Comment: You have read `No tests were executed`?

Comment: Yes I am getting this below error

Comment: Also read `Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.`?

Comment: Yes when I run my project with this command [clean install -DfailIfNoTests=false] in eclipse, my build was successful. But my java page was not launched

Comment: [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.20:test (default-test) @ Sanity ---
[INFO] No tests to run.

Comment: I tried command -X clean test -DfailIfNoTests=false also. Still, my java file is not invoked

Comment: Have you located your test file into `src/test/java` ? Have you named your test like `*Test.java` ?

Comment: My test file is in location src/test/SanityTest.java. Also, get this error when I run in debug mode[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20:test (default-test) on project Sanity: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20:test (default-test) on project Sanity: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)

Comment: Please remove the configuration for suite file from maven-surefire-plugin and retry..

Comment: what is your jdk version? if you are using java 7 version then you need to change the version of surefire plugin

Comment: I am using JDK1.8

Comment: @khmarbaise : I tried commenting configuration and suiteXML tags. Still same error

Answer (score 0):

are you getting error when you trying to build the project?
if yes the add the following plugin in your pom.xml i will ignore the test cases and build your project.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
         <configuration>
            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: just add this plugin into your pom.xml defiantly your projet will build...also make sure your internet connection is ok

Comment: <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.20</version>
    <configuration>
     <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
    <suiteXmlFiles>
    <suiteXmlFile>${sanitysuiteFile}</suiteXmlFile>
    </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  </plugins>

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue. Actually, the problem was with my POM.XML I defined my XML files in properties tag and passing as input to my surefire plugin. 
Now my POM.XML looks like

Properties:

```xml
<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <environment></environment>
  <browser></browser>
</properties>
```

SureFirePlugin:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.20</version>
  <inherited>true</inherited>
  <configuration>
    <suiteXmlFiles>
      <!-- Modify this parameter value based on the testtype -->
      <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
    </suiteXmlFiles>
    <systemPropertyVariables>
      <browserName>${environment}</browserName>
      <testRunID>${browser}</testRunID> 
    </systemPropertyVariables>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now my input is given from maven command line like

```
mvn -X clean test Denvironment=UAT Dbrowser=IE -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=sanity.xml
```

These values are retrieved in my java file using command System.getProperty("browser")