# TestNG - parallel executing Test Suites

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

There are 4 classes with tests `TestClass1, TestClasss2, TestClass3, TestClass4`. You need to create 2 test suites, each of which will include 2 classes and run them in parallel using the `Maven surefire plugin`.

I created 2 xml files with the following content:

```
<suite name="TestSuite" verbose="1">
    <test name="Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="Tests.TestClass1">
            </class>
            <class name="Tests.TestClass2">
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

and

```
<suite name="TestSuite1" verbose="1">
    <test name="Test1">
        <classes>
            <class name="Tests.TestClass3">
            </class>
            <class name="Tests.TestClass4">
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Also added to `pom.xml` in`maven-surefire-plugin` the following:

```
<configuration>
       <suiteXmlFiles>
           <suiteXmlFile>Testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
           <suiteXmlFile>Testng1.xml</suiteXmlFile>
       </suiteXmlFiles>
       <parallel>suite</parallel>
       <perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount>
       <threadCount>2</threadCount>
</configuration>
```

Next, I run the project with the command `mvn clean test`, the project is going to, but the tests do not start. Where was I wrong?

UPD:

The project is building, but the tests do not start

The file testng.xml is located in the root folder

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.469 sec - in T
estSuite

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.288 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-27T15:52:21+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please share the error log if available, and also make sure that Testng.xml file is in the proper location. In the above code, it is assumed that the Testng.xml is in the root project folder

Comment: Updated description

Comment: By the way. If you do not specify the path to xmlSuiteFile in pom.xml - there is no error. The project build passes correctly

Comment: The error seems to be different, error some where either in dependency management or sure-fire, This has nothing to do with the testng.xml. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427868/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-surefire-plugin2-12test/36429564 and also please ensure that there are no missing dependencies

Comment: I updated my maven plugin and this problem was solved. But now I ran into the next one. Look, plz, upd

Answer (score 0):

Try the following configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <suiteXmlFiles>
            <file>src/test/resources/testng.xml</file>
            <file>src/test/resources/testng1.xml</file>
        </suiteXmlFiles>
        <properties>
            <property>
                <name>suitethreadpoolsize</name>
                <value>2</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>surefire.testng.verbose</name>
                <value>10</value>
            </property>
        </properties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```