# Maven fails to compile spring-boot empty project

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I have downloaded a spring-boot empty project from Spring Initializr and when compiling it gives me the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project demo: There are test failures.
```

I've tried with both jdk 8 and 12, looks like it doesn't change anything.

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I've already read all the similar topics here but my problem is different. I have to use Maven and have not added any plugin yet.

Comment: `There are test failures.` - isn't it clear? :)

Comment: Yes but why? I haven't done anything.

Comment: Do you have no tests?

Comment: My test folder is empty, I'm running the project as downloaded.

Comment: I think this can help you: [Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427868/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-surefire-plugin2-12test)

Comment: @gipsy add `<maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>` in `<properties>` and try again

Comment: Please change the parent version to earlier stable one like 2.1.5.RELEASE. Later on right click on project and do the forceful updates of maven.

Comment: Right-click on "project" Go to "Maven" >> "Update" and check forceful update option

Comment: I've tried with everything and I still get the same error.

Comment: Try running mvn clean install and check the output. It should direct you to the issue.

Comment: That's exactly what I did to get that error.

Comment: And didnt it point you to where it tries to run the tests? Or which class that it tries to run?

Comment: [ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\User\Downloads\demo\demo\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved cleaning the Windows registry editor autorun of xampp.