# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project demo: There are test failures

Tags: selenium, jenkins, testng, pom.xml, maven-surefire-plugin

I added surefire plugins to my pom file but still getting error

Pom file

`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
    
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.13.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>4.0.1</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>29.0-jre</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
            <includes>
            R.java
            </includes>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.19.1</version>
        </plugin>     
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

`

Error after maven test

`

```
Results :

Failed tests: 
  RTest.beforetestTest:9 Runtime Test not implemented

Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.831 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-11-23T16:16:22+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project demo: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to E:\Eclipse_workspce\demo\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

`

[Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test (default-test) on project.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427868/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-surefire-plugin2-12test)

I tried to fix problem according to above link. But still I couldn't resolve the issue. Anyone can help?

Comment: What is the issue? Fix what causes test failure. We cannot know why your test fails.

Comment: I'm getting maven build failure when going to run as 'Maven test'.so I just want to successfully build this to run this project on Jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see you have runtime exception from beforeTest method. It looks like somebody intentionally added it.

Comment: I got comment thing that you have mentioned. Now its giving build success : )

Comment: Awesome, happy to hear