# Error while running Maven test Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

I'm working on a migration of my project from java 11 to 17.
I've some issues in surefire-plugin and due to this my maven test and maven build is failing.
If I skip the test by saying testfailureIgnore =  true then everything seems fine but this will not be a good approach because I've to pass the maven test.

I've also tried to do a/c to this question " [Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test (default-test) on project.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427868/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-surefire-plugin2-12test) " but nothing of them worked as I can't skip tests.
also I've tried to used the latest surefire plugin as well but that doesn't work.
Java version - openJdk 17.0.2
maven  - 3.8.7
Wildfly - 26
Error logs-
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/2bizq00xp405scqh6olzd/Untitled.paper?dl=0&rlkey=eip2f62cu4utbpj063rt3wsxa

pom.xml - https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/0mdpkej04lin0ikjds4a9/Untitled-1.paper?dl=0&rlkey=hu2zgfr5kp4ro4sq6jo04gr61

Adding my error message as text :

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/eclipse-jee-2022-09-R-win32-x86_64/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/maven-slf4j-provider-3.8.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/D:/eclipse-jee-2022-09-R-win32-x86_64/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/917/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.MavenSimpleLoggerFactory]
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/eclipse-jee-2022-09-R-win32-x86_64/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/maven-slf4j-provider-3.8.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/D:/eclipse-jee-2022-09-R-win32-x86_64/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/917/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.MavenSimpleLoggerFactory]
[[1;mINFO[m] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.apc:designportal:war:22.1.2
[WARNING] Reporting configuration should be done in <reporting> section, not in maven-site-plugin <configuration> as reportPlugins parameter. @ line 976, column 20
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO][1m------------------------<[0;36mcom.apc:designportal[0;1m >------------------------[m
[INFO][1mBuilding SE Design Portal 22.1.2[m
[INFO][1m--------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------[m
[WARNING] The POM for com.apc.designtools:dp-quotingsystem-integration:jar:0.4 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] 
[INFO][1m---[0;32mmaven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources[m[1m(default-resources)[m @[36mdesignportal[0;1m ---[m
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 14 resources
[INFO] Copying 83 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO][1m---[0;32mmaven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile[m[1m(default-compile)[m @[36mdesignportal[0;1m ---[m
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO][1m---[0;32mmaven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources[m[1m(default-testResources)[m @[36mdesignportal[0;1m ---[m
[3mWARNING[m] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 8 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO][1m---[0;32mmaven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:testCompile[m[1m(default-testCompile)[m @[36mdesignportal[0;1m ---[m
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO][1m---[0;32mmaven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test[m[1m(default-test)[m @[36mdesignportal[0;1m ---[m
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO][1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[INFO][1;31mBUILD FAILURE[m
[INFO][1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[INFO] Total time:  2.103 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-02-02T17:24:27+05:30
[INFO][1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] Failed to execute goal[32morg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test[m[1m(default-test)[m on project[36mdesignportal[m:[1;31mThere are test failures.[m
[ERROR]
[ERROR]Please refer to C:\Users\SESA701739\Downloads\Repository for openJDK17\designportal\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.[m
[ERROR]Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.[m
[ERROR]The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?[m
[ERROR]Command was cmd.exe /X /C "D:\eclipse-jee-2022-09-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.4.v20220903-1038\jre\bin\java -XX:MaxPermSize=256m org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter C:\Users\SESA701739\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire12444073772713059620 2023-02-02T17-24-27_412-jvmRun1 surefire15015576107840988338tmp surefire_06776565286570862578tmp"[m
[ERROR][1;31mError occurred in starting fork, check output in log[m
[ERROR][1;31mProcess Exit Code: 1[m
[ERROR][1;31morg.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?[m
[ERROR][1;31mCommand was cmd.exe /X /C "D:\eclipse-jee-2022-09-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.4.v20220903-1038\jre\bin\java -XX:MaxPermSize=256m org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter C:\Users\SESA701739\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire12444073772713059620 2023-02-02T17-24-27_412-jvmRun1 surefire15015576107840988338tmp surefire_06776565286570862578tmp"[m
[ERROR][Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log[m
[ERROR][Process Exit Code: 1[m
[ERROR][    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:671)[m
[ERROR][    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)[m
[ERROR][    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:278)[m
[ERROR][    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:244)[m
[ERROR][    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1194)[m
[ERROR][    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1022)[m
[ERROR][    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:868)[m
[ERROR][    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)[m
[ERROR][    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:370)[m
[ERROR][    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:351)[m
[ERROR][    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:215)[m
[ERROR][    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:171)[m
[ERROR][    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:163)[m
[ERROR][    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)[m
[ERROR][    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)[m
[ERROR][    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)[m
[ERROR][    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)[m
[ERROR][    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:294)[m
[ERROR][    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)[m
[ERROR][    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)[m
[ERROR][    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:960)[m
[ERROR][    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:293)[m
[ERROR][    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:196)[m
[ERROR][    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[m
[ERROR][    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)[m
[ERROR][    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[m
[ERROR][    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)[m
[ERROR][    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)[m
[ERROR][    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)[m
[ERROR][    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)[m
[ERROR][    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:7)[m
[ERROR][[
[ERROR] ->[1m[Help 1][m
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the[1m-e[m switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the[1m-X[m switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR][1m[Help 1][m http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: First please upgrade maven-surefire-plugin to most recent version https://maven.apache.org/plugins/ (also other plugins).

Comment: I’ve tried thar too but still this shows error only. @khmarbaise

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an error creating the forks.  You can adjust your surefire configuration to use a single fork, add this to the surefire plugin defined in your pom.

```
<configuration>
   <forkCount>1</forkCount>
   <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I added it but this did not work sir. Any other workaround on this.?