# Issue is using test maven, this error is displayed Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test)

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

When I am trying to test or install my pom.xml I received this error message:

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test
>   (default-test)

I want to specify that nothing really helped
Mvn clean, Update project, Clean or anything else that I can do related to maven, can anyone help me with others ideas that really can help solve the issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post the full error output and how you called Maven?

Comment: I am using Run As -> Maven install/test Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] Total time: 01:14 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-06-17T08:21:24+03:00
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project []: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test failed: The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called ? -> [Help 1]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170860/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-surefire-plugin2-10test

Answer (score -1):

Let me know if following info helps you or not !

- Try latest stable version of surefire-plugin (2.22.2)
- Other option might be memory Management

> ```
> <plugin>
>   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
>    <version>2.21.0</version>
>   <configuration>
>   <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
>     <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
>     <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
>   </configuration>
> </plugin>
> ```

- Please go through following threads which might help you.

  - http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/faq.html#vm-termination
  - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1422

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but is not working for me, is the same err

Comment: Can you provide pom.xml ?

Comment: POM contains too many characters I can not put it into a comment

Comment: Both pom.xml and TestNG.xml would be useful. I assume it has something to do with testNG xml also so just want to cross check.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/17enp64W5BZ9m4TFGO2CdSDqhp0ABtn-2RKY4Zewvb7A/edit            [] is only to remove important info

Comment: requested access

Comment: this is solved.. but only partially, the error now occurs in the middle of the tests during the tests are running

Comment: can anybody really help me with this ? Thanks

Comment: What you did to start execution? Also what maven version are you using?

Comment: apache maven3.6.0

Comment: Try using maven-surefire-plugin:2.11 since later version seems to have issue.
Reference - [SUREFIRE-1519](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1519)