# How to stop a maven build, if a junit test fails?

Tags: java, maven

I have set up a maven project, which is create a JAR File as artefact. Now I have created some JUnit tests and would like to stop the maven build, if one of these junit test fails. What steps are necessary, to do this? Now I get a JAR File, although one or more JUnit test fails.

I have created my JUnit test in the folder "src/main/resources" und here is the build  snippet of my pom.xml:

```
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <optimize>true</optimize>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <source>${source.jdk}</source>
                <target>${target.jdk}</target>                  
            </configuration>
        </plugin>   

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>
                        jar-with-dependencies
                    </descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>                      
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Source-JDK>${source.jdk}</Source-JDK>
                        <Target-JDK>${target.jdk}</Target-JDK>                                      
                        <Project-Build-SourceEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</Project-Build-SourceEncoding>    
                        <Maven-Build-Timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</Maven-Build-Timestamp>
                    </manifestEntries>
                    <manifest>  
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>                       
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}.myMainFile</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assembly-jar-Id</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 3):

When you create a `maven` project and if you use `mvn clean install` to build your source it will automatically fail your build saying test failures there is no need any other things.

Follow [this](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) to learn more.

Comment: As an additional info - if that does not happen to you most probably maven does not see and run your test classes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178583/maven-does-not-find-junit-tests-to-run

Answer (score 0):

> I have created my JUnit test in the folder "src/main/resources"

That's the wrong location. Put your unit test into "src/test/java" and Maven will take care of the rest.

Comment: sorry, that was my mistake. I put the junit test in src/test/java and not in src/main/resources

Answer (score -3):

I get that you are looking to 'fail-fast' but As far as my understanding the answer is NO.  On googling, I found a bug-issue raised for SureFire (the maven plugin that runs the junit test cases)

> Allow "fail fast" or stop running on first failure http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-580

which still is in Open state.

Comment: This is wrong. Using `maven` you can do what `OP` want. I am doing this more than a year now. This issue is about `surefire` plug-in not about `maven`

Answer (score -3):

You can add this to your command line : `mvn install -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true`
    or use the below plugin in your pom.xml :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${surefire.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- Build, even if tests fail -->
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

So even if any of your test fails it will ignore and continue your build process without failures.

Comment: Is this the thing Op want? Op don't want to continue his build, he want to fail his build if there is a test fail.

Comment: For build to stop as your test fails just make use of mvn clean install in your command prompt ,this will result in build failure if any of your test fails.

Comment: You should answer to OP question not something else.