# Arquillian Tests not executed

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, testing, jboss-arquillian

I have a multi module project, organised and built with maven. It consists of a war-module, an ejb-module and an ear-module. They alle have the same parent project (for dependencymanagement). Structure is like:

|- parent (packaging pom) 
|-- ejb-module 
|-- war-module 
|-- ear-module

Built order is first ejb-module then war-module than ear-module. The project depends on arquillian for testing. Both ejb-module and war-module contain a test. When I run "mvn clean test -Parq-wildfly-managed" (profile is to activate testing) the test of ejb-module is executed, but the test of war-module is not executed and there is no surefire-report in the target folder. There is no additional information on the output. I just get the message "No tests were executed". The War-Module depends on the Ejb-Module and

**Parent-Pom**

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>de.wilhelm</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>ejb-module</module>
    <module>web-module</module>
    <module>ear-module</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <!-- Explicitly declaring the source encoding eliminates the following 
    message: -->
    <!-- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered 
    resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <!-- JBoss dependency versions -->
    <version.wildfly.maven.plugin>1.0.2.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>

    <!-- Define the version of the JBoss BOMs we want to import to specify tested stacks. -->
    <version.jboss.bom>8.2.1.Final</version.jboss.bom>
    <version.wildfly>9.0.0.Alpha1</version.wildfly>


    <!-- other plugin versions -->
    <version.compiler.plugin>3.1</version.compiler.plugin>
    <version.ear.plugin>2.10</version.ear.plugin>
    <version.ejb.plugin>2.3</version.ejb.plugin>
    <version.surefire.plugin>2.16</version.surefire.plugin>
    <version.war.plugin>2.5</version.war.plugin>

    <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2-b01</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Define the version of the EJB jar so that we don't need 
        to repeat ourselves in every module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.wilhelm</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb-module</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Define the version of the WAR so that we don't need to repeat 
        ourselves in every module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.wilhelm</groupId>
            <artifactId>web-module</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE 7 APIs including
        a Bill of Materials (BOM). A BOM specifies the versions of a "stack" (or 
        a collection) of artifacts. We use this here so that we always get the correct 
        versions of artifacts. Here we use the jboss-javaee-7.0-with-tools stack
        (you can read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 7 APIs, with some extras
        tools for your project, such as Arquillian for testing) and the jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate
        stack you can read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 7 APIs, with extras
        from the Hibernate family of projects) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!-- The WildFly plugin deploys your ear to a local JBoss
            AS container -->
            <!-- Due to Maven's lack of intelligence with EARs we need 
            to configure the wildfly maven plugin to skip deployment for all modules.
            We then enable it specifically in the ear module. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

**EJB-Module POM**

```
 <parent>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>de.wilhelm</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>ejb-module</artifactId>
<packaging>ejb</packaging>

<name>EJB Module</name>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Declare the APIs we depend on and need for compilation. All of 
    them are provided by JBoss WildFly -->

    <!-- Import the EJB API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JPA API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSR-303 (Bean Validation) Implementation -->
    <!-- Provides portable constraints such as @Email -->
    <!-- Hibernate Validator is shipped in JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Test scope dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Optional, but highly recommended -->
    <!-- Arquillian allows you to test enterprise code such as EJBs and 
    Transactional(JTA) JPA from JUnit/TestNG -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>               
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.ejb.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Tell Maven we are using EJB 3.1 -->
                <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
    <!--             The default profile skips all tests, though you can tune it 
        to run just unit tests based on a custom pattern 
         Seperate profiles are provided for running all tests, including 
        Arquillian tests that execute in the specified container -->
        <id>default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.surefire.plugin}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
    <!--             An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests 
        in your WildFly instance 
         This profile will start a new WildFly instance, and execute
        the test, shutting it down when done 
         Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-wildfly-managed -->
        <id>arq-wildfly-managed</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>

    <profile>
    <!--             An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests 
        in a remote WildFly instance 
         Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-wildfly-remote -->
        <id>arq-wildfly-remote</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>

</profiles>
```

**WAR-Module POM**

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>de.wilhelm</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>web-module</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>WAR Module</name>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Dependency on the EJB module so we can use it's services if needed -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.wilhelm</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb-module</artifactId>
        <type>ejb</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JAX-RS API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JSF API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JPA API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSR-303 (Bean Validation) Implementation -->
    <!-- Provides portable constraints such as @Email -->
    <!-- Hibernate Validator is shipped in JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!--Test scope dependencies--> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--         Optional, but highly recommended 
     Arquillian allows you to test enterprise code such as EJBs and 
    Transactional(JTA) JPA from JUnit/TestNG -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>               
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Java EE 7 doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to catch up! -->
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!--             The default profile skips all tests, though you can tune it 
        to run just unit tests based on a custom pattern 
         Seperate profiles are provided for running all tests, including 
        Arquillian tests that execute in the specified container -->
        <id>default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.surefire.plugin}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <!--             An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests 
       in your WildFly instance 
        This profile will start a new WildFly instance, and execute
       the test, shutting it down when done 
        Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-wildfly-managed -->
        <id>arq-wildfly-managed</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <!--             An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests 
       in a remote WildFly instance 
        Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-wildfly-remote -->
        <id>arq-wildfly-remote</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>

</profiles>
```

**Test class of EJB-Module (gets executed)**

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class AccountEntityFacadeTest {
@Deployment
public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
            .addClasses(AccountEntity.class, AccountEntityFacade.class, AbstractFacade.class, AccountEntityBuilder.class)
            .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml") // activates CDI
            .addAsResource("META-INF/test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
            .addAsWebInfResource("test-ds.xml", "test-ds.xml");
}

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "primary")
public EntityManager em;

@Inject
AccountEntityFacade userFacade;

@Inject
AccountEntityBuilder accountBuilder;

@Before
public void prepare() throws Exception {
    clearData();
}

private void clearData() throws Exception{
}

@After
public void clear() throws Exception {
}

@Test
public void crudOperations() {
      // valid create operations
    AccountEntity a = accountBuilder.buildMemberAccount("a@a", "a", "a");
    AccountEntity b = accountBuilder.buildMemberAccount("b@b", "b", "b");
    userFacade.create(a);
    userFacade.create(b);
    AccountEntity aLoaded = userFacade.find(a.getEmail());
    assert(aLoaded.equals(a));
    }
}
```

**Test class of WAR-Module (not executed)**

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class AccountRestIT {

@Deployment
public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
            .addClasses(AccountRest.class)
            .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml") // activates CDI
            .addAsResource("META-INF/test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
            .addAsWebInfResource("test-ds.xml", "test-ds.xml");
}

@Inject
AccountRest accountRest;

@Before
public void prepare() throws Exception {
}

@After
public void clear() throws Exception {
}

@Test
public void testRestApi() {
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
}
```

I already tried to remove the profiles and run tests on default but the war-module tests were still not recognized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`public class AccountRestIT`   vs. `public class AccountEntityFacadeTest`

`surefire-maven-plugin` does not recognize tests that ends with `*IT`. You should change it's name to `*Test` or use other technique. For reference see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178583/maven-does-not-find-junit-tests-to-run/6178629#6178629) answer.

Comment: This enabled me to run arquillian tests for wildfly-quickstart-24.0.1.Final/kitchenskink, which comes with a class named `MemberRegistrationIT`. Simply renaming it to `MemberRegistrationTest` solved my issue. Many thanks!