# Maven does not identify the junit test

Tags: java, maven, junit

I have junit and spring-test dependencies in my pom file. When i run the test goal of maven using eclipse it does not identify my test class.

```
maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) @ media-project ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
```

I have the test class start with Test and also methods start with test.

Comment: By default, tests location must be `src/test/java`. can you show your pom.xml?

Comment: Also By default, test class names must inform of "**/Test*.java", "**/*Test.java" or "**/*TestCase.java" according to [surefire-plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html).

Comment: Sow your pom the path where your test clases are located and a sample test class to see if you write Junit3 or 4 tests.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven does not find JUnit tests to run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178583/maven-does-not-find-junit-tests-to-run)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should follow the test conventions: Put you tests in the `src/test/java` location as opposed to the `src/main/java` where you put your normal code. Also the filenames *have* to match

```
"**/Test*.java"
"**/*Test.java"
"**/*TestCase.java"
```

See [here](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html)