# Maven does not find unit tests to run, no Junit tests are executed Java

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, pom.xml

When run `mvn clean install` my project builds successfully howver it does not run any unit tests I have set up.

My code is located:
`src/main/java`

and my unit test:
`src/test/java`

When I run the Junit test independently (i.e. right click UnitTest.java Run As -> Junit Test) it works just fine. Only when I do `mvn clean install` or `mvn clean test`, it doesn't work.

I'm using default package (so all my classes are located directly under the java sub folders)

Here is the console output:

> ### -------------------------------------------------------  T E S T S
>
> Results :
>
> Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
>
> [INFO]  [INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.1:exec (generate-output) @
>   print-engine-tester --- [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar
>   (default-jar) @ print-engine---

Someone mentioned that it could be due to a TestNG depdendency involved with Junit 3, not sure if this is the case but I added the exclusion to my pom but still same problem.

Any help or assistance would be much appreciated

Edit:

Posting my unit test methods. I don't think naming convention is my issue

```
@Before
public void TestdBefore() throws Exception {

    Engine app = new Engine();
    app.run(DEFAULT_CONTENT_DIR, DEFAULT_FONTS_DIR, 
            DEFAULT_FORMML_DIR, DEFAULT_PDF_DIR, DEFAULT_CHK_DIR);
}

@Test
public void TestdTest() {
    CompareUtil util = new CompareUtil();
    util.run(FY2014, FY2015, formMLDir);
}

@After
public void TestdAfter() {

}
```

Comment: please check the link for the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178583/maven-does-not-find-junit-tests-to-run

Comment: I saw that one, but I don't think my problem is naming convention of my test methods

Comment: The answer isn't about test _"methods"_, but test _"classes"_

Comment: Unrelated, but I *would* recommend following Java naming conventions for your test methods.

Comment: Wow...spent spent like 30minutes just trying to figure this out. This worked but this is weird why would this happen? Never seen this issue before

Comment: Another thing to check. The test classes are not annotated with `@Ignore`, right?

Comment: Perhaps you followed the convention before, or weren't relying on the standard test runner.

Comment: @Arabian_albert, can you please post your POM.xml?

Comment: I just removed it, I will repost it when I get in front of a computer