# Surefire is not picking up Junit 5 tests

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin, junit5

I wrote a simple test method with JUnit 5:

```
public class SimlpeTest {
    @Test
    @DisplayName("Some description")
    void methodName() {
        // Testing logic for subject under test
    }
}
```

But when I run `mvn test`, I got:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running SimlpeTest
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Somehow, surefire didn't recognize that test class. My `pom.xml` looks like:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <junit.version>5.0.0-SNAPSHOT</junit.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit5-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>snapshots-repo</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Right now you have to use a special implementation of the surefire-plugin. Check the examples of the junit team [here](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/master/junit5-maven-consumer/pom.xml)

Comment: The question is based on an outdated version but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36970518/2525313) is based on the current one (as of December 2016).

Comment: @Nicolai Thanks for updating the answer. Anyway I would appreciate your edit on question, if you have the time.

Comment: This error does not occur like that anymore. The most likely case for a lack of test execution is covered by [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38993446/2525313).

Comment: Make sure the test files are in the right place. By default test should be a sibling of main under the src folder.

Comment: Please see [this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51838295/10816587) for current versions (2.22.x) of the surefire-plugin. Adding _<artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>_ oder _<artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>_ as a dependency (not in the plugin) may help.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

The `maven-surefire-plugin`, as of today, does [not have full support of JUnit 5](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/featurematrix.html). There is an open issue about adding this support in [SUREFIRE-1206](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1206).

As such, you need to use a [custom provider](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/providers.html). One has already been developed by the JUnit team; from the [user guide](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven), you need to add the `junit-platform-surefire-provider` provider and the `TestEngine` implementation for the new API:

```
<build>
  <plugins>        
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <!-- latest version (2.20.1) does not work well with JUnit5 -->
      <version>2.19.1</version>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
          <version>5.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Also, be sure to declare the `junit-jupiter-api` dependency with a scope of `test`:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Worth to note that at this moment surefire 2.20.1 doesn't work with junit 5 provider thus 2.19.1 used in sample is still valid despite of passed year.

Comment: surefire 2.21.0 doesn't work too, have to rollback to 2.19.1

Comment: @valodzka For me it does work with 2.21.0 and newer versions of the plugin and junit5. See https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven

Comment: Verified: `maven-surefire-plugin v2.21.0` works fine with `junit-jupiter-engine v5.2.0` and  `junit-platform-surefire-provider v1.2.0`

Comment: This works for me!. Thanks!. I am using spring-boot 2.0.4.RELEASE. Also with maven-surefire-plugin 2.21.0 did not work.

Comment: November 2018: still have to use junit-platform-surefire-provider, at version 1.3.1, [even though the Junit documentation claims otherwise](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven).

Comment: This config will fail with Surefire 2.22.0 or higher. You need to exclude the Junit deps from the Surefire config. I wrote a quick post about it here - https://springframework.guru/why-your-junit-5-tests-are-not-running-under-maven/

Comment: The junit-platform-surefire-provider has been deprecated and is scheduled to  
 be removed in JUnit Platform 1.4. Please use the built-in support in Maven    
 Surefire >= 2.22.0 instead.                                                   
 https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven

Comment: > be sure to declare the junit-jupiter-api dependency with a scope of test::::

Thanks! This was the clue when Maven stopped detecting my JUnit 5 tests after upgrading `junit-jupiter` from `5.8.2` to `5.9.0`.

Answer (score 79):

### **Update 2**

[Issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1330) has been fixed in Maven Surefire Plugin v2.22.0

[New version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.22.0) is available at Maven Central Repository.

**Maven**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Gradle**

```
compile group: 'org.apache.maven.plugins', name: 'maven-surefire-plugin', version: '2.22.0'
```

---

### **Update**

As [Marian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8471555/marian) pointed out, the latest version of **JUnit 5 Platform Surefire Provider (1.2.0)** supports latest version of **Maven Surefire Plugin (2.21.0)**:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

---

**Example**

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**TestScenario.java**

```
package test;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class TestScenario {

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Test 2 + 2 = 4")
    public void test() {
        Assertions.assertEquals(4, 2 + 2);
    }
}
```

**Output (mvn clean install)**

> ... 
>   [INFO] --- **maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0**:test (default-test) @ test ---
>   [INFO] 
>  [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------- 
>  [INFO]  T E S T S 
>  [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------- 
>  [INFO] Running test.TestScenario 
>  [INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0,
>   Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 s - in test.TestScenario
>   
>  [INFO] 
>  [INFO] Results: 
>  [INFO] 
>  [INFO] **Tests run: 1**,
>   Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0 
>   ...

---

Simplest way till today:

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: This only works because of *Test* in the name of the class. Rename the class to ExampleScenario - it will not be discovered. (Surefire 2.22.0)

Comment: @AlexeiVinogradov Yes. It's expected behavior. More information available here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6178629/3523579

Comment: bevare, junit engine version vs. spring boot parent version. Just specify dependency junit-jupiter-engine:5.1 does not work where newer versions does. Spring boot has 
 still preconfigured JUnit4 <junit.version>4.13.

Answer (score 25):

From the [JUnit 5 documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven) :

> Starting with version `2.22.0`, Maven Surefire provides native support
>   for executing tests on the JUnit Platform.

Additionally you can  read in the [`maven-surefire-plugin` documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html) :

> **Using JUnit 5 Platform**
>
> To get started with JUnit Platform, you need to add at least a single
>   `TestEngine` implementation to your project. For example, if you want to
>   write tests with Jupiter, add the test artifact `junit-jupiter-engine`
>   to the dependencies in POM

So just that is enough to make run JUnit 5 tests :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>davidxxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>minimal-pom-junit5</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <junit-jupiter.version>5.2.0</junit-jupiter.version> 
        <!--optional below but good practice to specify our java version-->
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--optional below -->
        <!-- add any JUnit extension you need such as -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

On my GitHub space I added a working sample maven project that you can browse/clone.
URL: https://github.com/ebundy/junit5-minimal-maven-project

Answer (score 20):

I encountered the same problem in August 2019 which I asked about here: [Maven silently fails to find JUnit tests to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57478539/maven-silently-fails-to-find-junit-tests-to-run).  These answers led me in the right direction, but I found that you can solve the problem even more concisely.  I copied my solution from the [JUnit5 sample Maven project](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/r5.5.1/junit5-jupiter-starter-maven).

As of JUnit 5.5.1 and `maven-surefire-plugin` 2.22.2, you do not need to add the `junit-platform-surefire-provider` dependency.  It is enough to have this one dependency and one plugin specified in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: This is the correct and concise approach. Works with OpenJDK 11 and JUnit 5.6.2.

Comment: perfect for me, the other options have not worked

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this issue with JUnit5 and Maven but also noticed that, even if **only** junit-jupiter-engine was added as a dependency, **tests would run on some projects, not on others**. And I kind of see the same pattern in the comments here: In @Alex comment above you can see he doesn't have any issue, even with earlier versions of surefire/junit/platform.

After scratching my head for some time I realized that those projects where the tests wouldn't run were those where the tests **method** names dit **not** contain the word "test". Though this isn't mandated by http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

In other words:
just with

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

this

```
@Test
public void something() {
    assertTrue(true);
}
```

will NOT be run, whereas

```
@Test
public void testSomething() {
    assertTrue(true);
}
```

WILL be run !

This issue unfolds as a russian doll...

Anyway, +1 for @Mikhail Kholodkov whose updated answer fixes all the issues at once!

Comment: I have also just experienced an issue with mvn 3.5.0, jdk 1.8.0_101 where my class name did not have 'Test' in and the test was not picked up, this helped me find that!

Comment: Yeah indeed you should be compliant to http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html
But I was talking about something different.

Comment: Yes it turned out I had two problems, the first was not remembering the basic maven surefire test rules. The second was not doing a Maven > update project for eclipse to pick up the junit 5 launcher.

Comment: I would like to add that the class and methods must be public.

Answer (score 6):

Just to complement, surefire 2.22.0 + junit 5.2.0 + platform 1.2.0 also works. Attached is a working pom for your referecne:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.jjhome.junit5</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit5-hone</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>junit5-home</name>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <junit5.version>5.2.0</junit5.version>
        <platform.version>1.2.0</platform.version>
        <surefire.version>2.22.0</surefire.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit5.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>${junit5.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit5.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit5.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>${platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
            <version>${platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>${platform.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>${junit5.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: My issue was that I did not have `junit-vintage-engine` as a dependency, and all of my tests were written for JUnit 4.

Comment: the combination of specified junit, platform and surefire versions worked for me. thanks !

Answer (score 6):

In my case this was because of the TestNG in the classpath ([SUREFIRE-1527](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1527)). Groovy 2.5.5 POM have brought it with the `groovy-testng` module.

Manually specified test-framework provider (as it's described at the https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/providers.html) solved the problem:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-junit-platform</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: You should wrap the `<dependency>` in `<dependencies>` in your code sample.

Comment: you saved me thanks...groovy-all included groovy-testng and after excluding it....tests are running

Answer (score 4):

**Update 2022**

The following now works:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

And of-course the dependency added:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The tests are now detected.

Comment: It seems we are back to this problem again with 3.0.0-x.

Answer (score 3):

One thing I noticed that I was able to get it working:

- Naming my test class `ClinicCalendarShould` does not get picked up by maven
- Naming my test class `ClinicCalendarTest` DOES get picked up by maven

So, unless I am missing some sort of configuration or parameter or whatever in the surefire plugin, by default, you need to name your test classes XXXTest.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue both `junit5` and `maven-surefire` tests were failing. However `junit4` was running fine. Below combination worked for me, I don't add the versioning. Use `junit-bom` for dependency management. Using `spring-boot` `2.1.4`

```
   <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.6.1</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Make sure to upgrade to the latest version of eclipse

Answer (score 1):

[There is open issue for surefire 2.20](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/809)

It is working for me with surfire 2.19 + junit-platform-* 1.0.3

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem also causing Surefire to recognize zero tests.

My problem turned out to be related to the following (from the [JUnit 5.1.0 / maven](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven) documentation):

> Due to a memory leak in Surefire 2.20 and issues running on Java 9, the junit-platform-surefire-provider currently only works with Surefire 2.19.1.

I was trying to use the latest versions of Surefire (2.21.0) and junit-platform-surefire-provider (1.1.0), and it did not work (in neither Java 8 or 9)

Switching back to Surefire 2.19.1 solved my problem.

According to [this issue](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1341) a fix will be included in version 1.2.0 of the junit-platform-surefire-provider (currently available as SNAPSHOT only).

Comment: I've tried the SNAPSHOTs and all is working (with Surefire 2.21.0). Hopefully it be still working at the time of release.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the surefire plugin didn't get the correct version auf the jupiter-engine/api. And that was even if running Maven 3.6.1 und surefireplugin Version 2.22.2!

Now my surefire-plugin configuration looks like:

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>5.5.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        ...
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Further more, I had to force these Versions:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Looks like 5.5.2 was linked to the wrong platform version 1.3.2 instead of 1.5.2 in my case.

All JUnit5 Tests gets picked up now. Even with 2.22.0 of the surefire plugin this wasn't the case for me!

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

Updating to `maven-surefire-plugin:2.20` runs the Junit5 tests with no problem.

But I am using the `M6` version on Junit5.

Comment: Not that simple (at least at the moment). See [JUnit 5 User Guide](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven)

Comment: @FrVaBe weird its works just fine on mine with the m6 version.

Comment: I tired surefire-2.20.1 + junit-5.0.2 and it didn't work.  I also tried surefire-2.20.1 + junit-5.1.0-M6 and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with nested tests. I had a test class like this:

```java
class AcrTerminalTest {
    @Nested
    class card_is_absent {
        AcrTerminal acrTerminal = new AcrTerminal(new CardAbsentFakeCardTerminal());

        @Test
        void isCardPresent_returns_false() {
            assertThat(acrTerminal.isCardPresent())
                    .isFalse();
        }
    }
}
```

Running just `./mvnw test -Dtest=AcrTerminalTest` failed, I needed to add `*` after test class name like this `./mvnw test -Dtest=AcrTerminalTest\*` (see the asterisk).

Answer (score 0):

This was commented by **schnell18** some lines above https://stackoverflow.com/a/51796487/1619489

For me was such easy as:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.5</version>
</parent>

<build>
    <finalName>app-console-services</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

... And this dependency...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my case experience there **should be no dependency** on library *junit-jupiter-engine* in pom.xml. Then one can use plugin maven-surefire-plugin and dependency on *junit-jupiter* of the newest version

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem when upgrading from junit 4 to 5.

from

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>junit</groupId>
       <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
       <version>4.12</version>
       <type>jar</type>
       <scope>test</scope>
       <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I used an Eclipse feature to create the unit test class.  Right click the class file to test --> New --> Other --> Junit Test Case --> New JUnit Jupiter test.  This will nicely create a stubbed out Unit Test class.  Beware however as the stubbed out Unit Test class will NOT have the **public** class identifier nor will the corresponding annotated test method(s) be **public**.

The unit test will run fine in Eclipse but when run from bash, 'mvn test', the corresponding test will not be detected (no warning either).

```
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

If you revert to junit 4, 'mvn test' will warn you.

```
Tests in error:
initializationError(com.mycompany.operations.ConvertExcelTest): The class com.mycompany.operations.ConvertExcelTest is not public.
  initializationError(com.mycompany.operations.ConvertExcelTest): Test class should have exactly one public constructor
  initializationError(com.mycompany.operations.ConvertExcelTest): Method testExecute_excel97File() should be public
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 0
```

The solution for me was to make the corresponding test class public and to make the test method public too.

```
public class ConvertExcelTest {

@Test
public void testExecute_excel97File() {
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, which is why I ended up here. For me, I had jupiter on the classpath and surefire was at 3.2.2 and was running with the `@SpringBootTest` annotation so most of the advice here was/is out of date.

The key thing for me from running the tests was:

```
...
[INFO] --- surefire:3.2.2:test (default-test) @ my-tests ---
[INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnit3Provider
...
```

The [surefire website provides](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/providers.html) instructions on how to select a provider.

Essentially, for me this fixed it against junit5:

```xml
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit-platform</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Dspring.profiles.active=${spring.profiles.active} ${args}</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

At the time of posting surefire have these providers:

`The providers supplied with Surefire are surefire-junit3, surefire-junit4, surefire-junit47, surefire-junit-platform and surefire-testng.`

Answer (score 0):

You need check your JUnit version.

If nothing is configured, Surefire detects which JUnit version to use by the following algorithm:

```
if the JUnit 5 Platform Engine is present in the project
    use junit-platform
if the JUnit version in the project >= 4.7 and the <<<parallel>>> configuration parameter has ANY value
    use junit47 provider
if JUnit >= 4.0 is present
    use junit4 provider
else
    use junit3.8.1
```

You can also force a specific provider by adding it as a dependency to Surefire itself.

For example:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score -1):

For me the solution is adding the annotation below on top of the class.

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
public class MyTest {
 ....
}
```

Then even the surefire plugin is not required.

Comment: `@RunWith` is from JUnit 4, so I don't think that applies to this question about JUnit 5 tests.  (You should add `junit-vintage-engine` as a dependency to `maven-surefire-plugin` if you want to run JUnit 4 tests under JUnit 5.)