# Cannot create Launcher without at least one TestEngine; consider adding an engine implementation JAR to the classpath in Junit 5

Tags: java, maven, junit5

I got following execption when i tried to run test case in junit5:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19:test (default-test) on project CRUD-App: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
org.junit.platform.commons.util.PreconditionViolationException: Cannot create Launcher without at least one TestEngine; consider adding an engine implementation JAR to the classpath
   at org.junit.platform.commons.util.Preconditions.condition(Preconditions.java:161)
   at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.<init>(DefaultLauncher.java:52)
   at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory.create(LauncherFactory.java:42)
   at org.junit.platform.surefire.provider.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:59)
   at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:286)
   at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:240)
   at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit5-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>        
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0-M2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Test Class:**

```
public class PersonServiceTest {

    final Database database = Database.from("jdbc:h2:mem:" + App.DB_NAME);

    final PersonService personService = new PersonService(database);

    public PersonServiceTest() {
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("@Person#insert()")
    public void testInsert() {
        personService.insert(new PersonBuilder()
                .setId(1).setName("Bhuwan")
                .setAddress("KTM")
                .setContactNo("984849").createPerson()
        );
    }

}
```

**Maven Goal:**  `mvn test`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Mixing **ALPHA** snapshot artifacts (i.e., `org.junit:junit5-api:5.0.0-SNAPSHOT`) with **M2** artifacts (i.e., `org.junit.platform:junit-platform-surefire-provider:1.0.0-M2`), won't work.

The [Maven](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0-M2/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven) section in the user guide suggests to check out the [`pom.xml`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/master/junit5-maven-consumer/pom.xml) from the [junit5-maven-consumer](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/r5.0.0-M2/junit5-maven-consumer) project. If you follow that example, you will end up with something like the following.

```xml
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <junit.jupiter.version>5.0.0-M2</junit.jupiter.version>
    <junit.platform.version>1.0.0-M2</junit.platform.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

To *write* your tests, you only need the `junit-jupiter-api`; however, in order to *run* your tests you must have a `TestEngine` on the classpath. For JUnit Jupiter you therefore need `junit-jupiter-engine` on the classpath as well.

As Nicolai Parlog pointed out, you could add `junit-jupiter-engine` as a dependency for the `maven-surefire-plugin`; however, that would not include the `JupiterTestEngine` in the classpath for your IDE.

If you're only running tests via Maven or with a recent beta version of IntelliJ 2016 (which has built-in support for JUnit 5), then you may not care if `JupiterTestEngine` is on the classpath in your IDE. But... if you're using Eclipse, NetBeans, or a non-beta version of IntelliJ, you'll definitely want the `JupiterTestEngine` on the classpath in the IDE as well.

Regards,

Sam (*core JUnit 5 committer*)

Answer (score 27):

Ended up here since getting the same error using Gradle and JUnit 4. The solution in this case can be found in the [docs](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-gradle-engines-configure):

> The JUnit Platform can run JUnit 4 based tests as long as you
> configure a testImplementation dependency on JUnit 4 and a
> testRuntimeOnly dependency on the JUnit Vintage TestEngine
> implementation similar to the following.

A test engine is also needed:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.8.2")
}
```

Answer (score 16):

simply adding below dependency solved this prob.

```
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2'
```

Answer (score 12):

The Maven Surefire plugin not only needs the JUnit 5 provider but also a `TestEngine` implementation to run tests with. To quote the [JUnit 5 docs](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven):

> In order to have Maven Surefire run any tests at all, a `TestEngine`
>   implementation must be added to the runtime classpath.

In accordance with that the following works:

```
<build>
    <plugins>        
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0-M4</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>5.0.0-M4</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-M4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Note that this configuration makes the engine a dependency of the surefire plugin, *not* of your test code.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it changing

`classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.8.RELEASE"`

to

`classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.2.0.RELEASE"`