# Cannot create Launcher without at least one TestEngine, PreconditionViolationException

Tags: java, spring, junit5

I want to run all test at the start of my app. But i get: 
Exception in thread "main" org.junit.platform.commons.util.PreconditionViolationException: Cannot create Launcher without at least one TestEngine; consider adding an engine implementation JAR to the classpath

Already tried adding surefire-plugin to plugin section. Tried some different junit versions as well... nothing helped.

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apiguardian</groupId>
            <artifactId>apiguardian-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <junit-jupiter.version>5.4.0</junit-jupiter.version>
        <junit.platform.version>1.3.2</junit.platform.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Tried to add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.spek</groupId>
    <artifactId>spek-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.89</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

didn't help either

Comment: You add Jupiter only in test scope. Your app probably needs it in runtime/compile scope.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot create Launcher without at least one TestEngine; consider adding an engine implementation JAR to the classpath in Junit 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993446/cannot-create-launcher-without-at-least-one-testengine-consider-adding-an-engin)

Comment: Tried solutions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993446/cannot-create-launcher-without-at-least-one-testengine-consider-adding-an-engin but it didnt work