# Unable to execute Junit5 tests using Maven

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, junit5

Maven execution

```
mvn clean test
```

I am trying to use `junit5` for one of my maven projects but not able to execute the unit tests during the `test` phase using  -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0-M3</version>
</dependency>
```

The output that I get is -

> ```
> [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) @ utils ---
>
> -------------------------------------------------------
>  T E S T S
> -------------------------------------------------------
>
> Results :
>
> Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
> ```

---

Tried implementing the solution mentioned @ [Surefire is not picking up Junit 5 tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36970384/surefire-is-not-picking-up-junit-5-tests) to update the dependencies to -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0-M3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit5-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0-ALPHA</version><!--https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit/junit5-api -->
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and updating the plugin to  -

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-ALPHA</version><!--couldn't find this on the central though-->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

but the output remains same.

***Question*** - Is this custom provider no more supported or is there any solution to executing the tests using `maven`, `junit5` and/or `junit5-api`  currently?

***Note*** - The test execution was working fine with JUnit-4.

Comment: How is your project structured? What directory are your unit tests in?

Comment: They are in the corresponding `src/test` folder itself. In fact, generated using intelliJ's shortcut to create Unit Tests. Would update that things are good with `junit4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should configure the maven-surefire-plugin like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-M3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

You only need to include the junit-jupiter-api artifact and only in test scope in your dependencies section:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0-M3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Please see http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven for more information.

***Edit*** - From the same docs.

> In order to have Maven Surefire run any tests at all, a `TestEngine`
>   implementation must be added to the runtime classpath.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-M3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-M3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```