# Mock autowired dependency in JUnit 5 test for Spring Boot 2 app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, junit5

Consider the following class under test:

```
public class SomeClass {

    @Autowired
    private SomeDependency someDependency;

    public int inc(int i) {
        someDependency.doSomething();
        return i + 1;
    }

}
```

How can I mock (preferably with Mockito) `someDependency` in a JUnit 5 (`5.0.1`) test for a Spring Boot 2 (`2.0.0.M2`) application? When I try to invoke `SomeClass#inc(int)` it yields a `NullPointerException` because the autowired dependency isn't injected.

Comment: you should show the test class.

Comment: @davidxxx it doesn't contain useful information I think. I just need a way to inject the mock.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mockito 1 runner (`MockitoJUnitRunner` class) is not designed to run JUnit 5 tests.

So annotating your class with :

```
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) 
public class MyJUnit5Test {
```

will have no effect.

To be able to use the `@Mock` annotation, you could invoke before each test :

```
 MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

in a method annotated with JUnit 5 `@BeforeEach`.
But from now a better alternative to not repeat this pre-processing in each JUnit test class is using the [`MockitoExtension` class provided by the `mockito-junit-jupiter` dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter/2.22.0).

---

**Code example**

Supposing the `SomeDependency` class declared as :

```
@Component
public class SomeDependency {

    public String returnThat() {
        return "that";
    }
}
```

You could so mock the dependency in this way in your unit test :

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import davidhxxx.example.angularsboot.SomeDependency;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)    
public class SomeClassTest {

    @Mock
    SomeDependency someDependencyMock;

    private SomeClass someClass;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup(){
      someClass = new SomeClass(someDependencyMock);
    }

    @Test 
    void myFirstTest() {
      Mockito.when(someDependencyMock.returnThat()).thenReturn("mock result");
      Assertions.assertEquals("mock result", someClass.inc());
    }

}
```

Note that `SomeClass` has to provide a way to set its `SomeDependency`  dependency.
You should add a constructor that accepts an instance of.
Using `setter` is also a way while it provides mutability.

---

**pom.xml requirements**

1) You can add `the spring-boot-starter-test` dependency that includes Mockito and other useful things in inherited dependencies :

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
   ...
</dependencies>
```

Add also the `junit-jupiter-engine` dependency and all other optional JUnit 5 dependencies that you require :

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.0</version> <!-- version to specify as not provided by Spring Boot dependencies -->
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

You don't need to specify version for the `junit-jupiter-engine` artifact but you may need for other JUnit 5 dependencies such as `junit-jupiter-params`.
Hoping that this would be not required any longer in next versions of Spring Boot.

2) Beware : if you use a Spring Boot version that pulls the 
2.20 version of the `maven-surefire-plugin` it will not work. So you will have to override the `maven-surefire-plugin` plugin configuration to specify a version compatible with JUnit 5 (that is 2.19 or 2.21 and later).
For example the 2.0.0.M5 version of Spring Boot pulls maven-surefire-plugin:2.20 and so reconfiguring the plugin such as the following is required :

```
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
     ...
   <plugins>
```

It will generate a Maven warning :

> Overriding managed version 2.20.1 for maven-surefire-plugin

Good news : from the 2.0.1.RELEASE version of Spring Boot this issue is solved as the maven-surefire-plugin version was updated to use `2.21.0` and later version that solves the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the great example. I somehow still get a `NullPointerException` (see edit). BTW: I'm trying to test `SomeClass`, not `SomeDependency`.

Comment: This works, but only if I add a corresponding constructor (currently, there's no `SomeClass(@Autowired SomeDependency sd)`).

Comment: Sure. Having a constructor to define dependencies is a good thing. "Hiding " dependencies as private fields doesn't make the class testable.

Comment: Indeed, thank you! (And thanks for pointing out the issue with the Surefire plugin, I've been struggling with this before.)

Comment: For the sake of completeness: As of version `2.21.0`, the Failsafe plugin supports JUnit 5, no additional configuration is needed. (Comes with Spring Boot `2.0.1.RELEASE`.)

Comment: Thanks for this update. I update with this point. And for information the `2.22.0` is still better as it doesn't require any additional configuration in the surefire/failsafe Maven plugin.  But I don't know when Spring Boot will add it. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36970384/surefire-is-not-picking-up-junit-5-tests)