# How do I run JUnit 5 integration tests with the Maven Failsafe plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-failsafe-plugin, junit5

The Maven Failsafe plugin won't find my JUnit 5 integration tests when I'm running the command `mvn clean failsafe:integration-test`, although it can find the files.

I have the `junit-jupiter-api` and `junit-jupiter-engine` as test dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <junit.jupiter.version>5.0.1</junit.jupiter.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My integration tests are named correctly (following the `**/*IT.java`, `**/IT*.java`, or the `**/*ITCase.java` that included by default by Failsafe and excluded by default by Surefire).

Is there any way that I can use JUnit 5 tests with Failsafe?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Note that from [the JUnit 5 documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven) : `junit-platform-surefire-provider` should be not used any longer :

> Due to the release of Surefire `2.22.0`, the
>   `junit-platform-surefire-provider` from the JUnit team has been
>   deprecated and will be discontinued in a subsequent release of the
>   JUnit Platform.

Additionally, you can also read in the [`maven-surefire-plugin` documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html) :

> **Using JUnit 5 Platform**
>
> To get started with JUnit Platform, you need to add at least a single
>   `TestEngine` implementation to your project. For example, if you want to
>   write tests with Jupiter, add the test artifact `junit-jupiter-engine`
>   to the dependencies in POM

So you have to specify this `test` dependency :

```
<properties>
    <junit-jupiter.version>5.2.0</junit-jupiter.version>
</properties> 

<dependencies>
     [...]
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
         <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
     [...] 
</dependencies>
```

And the `maven-failsafe-plugin` declaration could be as simple as :

```
<build>
    <plugins>           
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: @Thomas 'Panda' Attwood In fact it is not a workaround but the right way. I found the exact reference.

Comment: maven-failsafe-plugin version 2.22.0 doesn't support JUnit 5 natively yet.  When I upgraded to 2.22.0 and removed the dependencies section, maven ignored all of my JUnit5 integration tests.

Comment: @Tom Norton I agree. That's why I said that `junit-jupiter-engine` dependency was still required. But the platform dependency is not required any longer.

Comment: Something along those lines worked for me. Thanks for posting it. I still had issues with failsafe not finding the tests. It turned out to be related to our use of SpringBoot (which is not part of the original question but some may come here for answers). What helped me with that was to change the way the jar is packaged - following suggestions in this bug ticket about the incompatibility: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6254 (now I can run failsafe 2.22.2 with SpringBoot 2.2)

Answer (score 16):

**Edit:** This answer was correct before `maven-failsafe-plugin:2.22.0`. See [*davidxxx*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51837961/2876432) for the ideal and most up to date solution.

---

The `maven-failsafe-plugin` currently [doesn't support JUnit 5](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/featurematrix.html), out of the box.

However, [like with `maven-surefire-plugin`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36970384/surefire-is-not-picking-up-junit-5-tests), you can run JUnit 5 tests with the `maven-failsafe-plugin` by specifying the dependency on the `org.junit.platform:junit-platform-surefire-provider:1.0.1` with the earlier version of the `maven-failsafe-plugin:2.19.1`.

It doesn't work with the current version 2.20 of the failsafe (in the same way that the surefire has the error) due to an [`OutOfMemory` error](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/809).

See the below for an example of the configuration of the plugin:

```
<properties>
    <junit.platform.version>1.0.1</junit.platform.version>
</properties>

<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

You can find [a full example of this working (and a failing one) on GitHub](https://github.com/TickleThePanda/junit5-failsafe-example/). To test that it works, you can run `mvn clean failsafe:integration-test`.

Comment: Which "current" version does it not work with and why?

Comment: For me failsafe still doesn't pick up the integration tests. surefire doesn that.

Comment: Have the same issue as @KrzysztofKrasoń. My tests are not pick up by failsafe. :(

Comment: @KrzysztofKrasoń @dadoonet I've gone over this and tested it with an example (https://github.com/TickleThePanda/junit5-failsafe-example) and it still works for me. Have you named the Integration Tests correctly (by default Failsafe looks for `**/*IT.java`, `**/IT*.java`, and `**/*ITCase.java` which are also ignored by surefire)?

Comment: @Thomas'Panda'Attwood If I clone your repo and run `mvn clean install` from the non-faily dir it makes no mention of ExampleIT and also if I edit ExampleIT, changing it to assertTrue(false); it still succeeds. I'm using mvn v3.3.9 is this different for you?

Comment: The repo at github.com/TickleThePanda/junit5-failsafe-example is broken and doesn't run the integration tests because there is no executions element in the failsafe plugin.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't include the executions in there. I've updated the instructions in the `README.md` to that more clear now. (https://github.com/TickleThePanda/junit5-failsafe-example/commit/b4dbea943f2628c164acefbf0caf4aeb8801b7b9)