# mvn spring boot plugin breaks integration testing

Tags: maven, spring-boot, integration-testing, junit5, maven-failsafe-plugin

My integration testing with `maven-failsafe-plugin` and `JUnit5` was difficult to set up initially, but it now works:

```
plugins:
  - artifactId: maven-failsafe-plugin
    groupId: org.apache.maven.plugins
    version: 2.19.1
    dependencies:
      - artifactId: junit-platform-surefire-provider
        groupId: org.junit.platform
        version: 1.0.3
      - artifactId: junit-jupiter-engine
        groupId: org.junit.jupiter
        version: 5.1.1
    configuration:
        includes:
          - v3api/*IntegrationTests.java
    executions:
      - goals: [ integration-test, verify ]
```

However I then want to turn the artifact into a fat jar and it seems as if `spring-boot-maven-plugin` clashes with `maven-failsafe-plugin`, because if I put this config into my pom ...

```
  - artifactId: spring-boot-maven-plugin
    groupId: org.springframework.boot
    version: ${spring.boot.version}
    executions:
      - goals: [ repackage ]
    configuration:
        fork: true
        executable: true
        outputDirectory: ${project.build.directory}/binary
```

then I get this error instead on integration testing:

```
Jun 05, 2018 3:03:15 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/adam/api/DbAccess
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.getDefaultMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:1024)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:997)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.findAllMethodsInHierarchy(ReflectionUtils.java:939)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:923)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:909)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.JavaElementsResolver.resolveContainedMethods(JavaElementsResolver.java:189)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.JavaElementsResolver.resolveChildren(JavaElementsResolver.java:177)
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.JavaElementsResolver.resolveClass(JavaElementsResolver.java:61)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.lambda$resolve$3(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:69)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.resolve(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:68)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.resolveSelectors(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:50)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.JupiterTestEngine.discover(JupiterTestEngine.java:61)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:130)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:117)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:82)
    at org.junit.platform.surefire.provider.TestPlanScannerFilter.accept(TestPlanScannerFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.DefaultScanResult.applyFilter(DefaultScanResult.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.surefire.provider.JUnitPlatformProvider.scanClasspath(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:121)
    at org.junit.platform.surefire.provider.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.adam.api.DbAccess
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 28 more

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

In the [maven spring boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/maven-plugin/examples/it-skip.html) they describe how the plugin can be configured to start and stop the spring boot app for integration testing with the `pre-` and `post-integration-testing` lifecycle phases.

My app's life cycle is slightly different with a docker and kubernetes aspect. It goes like this:

- package the jar
- turn jar into a fat jar with the spring boot plugin
- dockerise it
- install it to docker registry
- deploy to dev
- integration testing
- promote build from dev to test
- deploy to test

I have tried binding the spring boot plugin to the `package` phase, but that makes no difference to the error.

Apart from the spring boot lifecycle phase issue, it could also have a lot to do with JUnit5, because `maven-failsafe-plugin` seems to be verging on unsupported for JUnit5: [How do I run JUnit 5 integration tests with the Maven Failsafe plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079105/how-do-i-run-junit-5-integration-tests-with-the-maven-failsafe-plugin#answer-47079107)

i've also seen this on [Spring plus JUnit Jupiter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-junit-jupiter) but it doesn't help with integration testing.

Comment: Maybe it is caused by Spring custom loader: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50804520, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6254#issuecomment-229599865

Answer (score 4):

The following works for me:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${springboot.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <!-- repackage will break the integration-test class-path, so schedule after -->
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

I can run integration tests via: `mvn verify`

And SpringBoot launches via: `java -jar target/my-jar.jar`

Comment: What if integration tests are in different module?

Answer (score 1):

I've done it using these plugins in hierarchical structure:

```
Parent
|
 \pom.xml (Added tests plugins including maven-failsafe-plugin)
|
 \ application-startup
   |
    \ pom.xml (Added spring-boot-maven-plugin)
```

By this way all your subprojects will be tested and only after that maven will assemble in a fat jar.