# Maven Failsafe: NoClassDefFoundError for integration tests

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, integration-testing, maven-surefire-plugin

Setup: Kotlin integration tests in a spring boot application.

Tests work fine when I run them with IntelliJ.
When I try to run the integration tests with maven, though:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.19.1:integration-test (default) on project myapp: Execution default of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.19.1:integration-test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/cypherk/myapp/service/CustomerService
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3138)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3343)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2152)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.PojoAndJUnit3Checker.isPojoTest(PojoAndJUnit3Checker.java:51)
...
```

which is very annoying since I kind of need bamboo to run the darn things.

The `CustomerService` is an interface and yes, it is compiled, there's a corresponding `.class` file in maven's `./target` directory and IntelliJ is set up to use the same.

Can't quite figure out why this is failing and would appreciate some help with the plugin.

Relavant excerpt from the `pom.xml`:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- doesn't make a difference if `true` or `false`-->
        <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*IT*</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/ui/*</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Full `pom.xml`: http://freetexthost.com/dbghyawijj

Full log of the failing integration test step: http://freetexthost.com/gbsmd3mwm2

Comment: First, try using the same version of the surefire and failsafe plugins. They are closely related. Not sure it will fix anything, but IMO consistency is the first step.

Comment: Also, the `<useSystemClassLoader>` attribute was added to the Surefire config, but it's Failsafe that's having the problem.

Comment: For Spring Boot see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50804520/8547799 and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6254

Comment: Are you using jmockit?

Answer (score 7):

Faced the same problem, sovled it by adding **target/classes** as additional classpath elements. It feels a little bit dirty but works:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <additionalClasspathElements>
            <additionalClasspathElement>${basedir}/target/classes</additionalClasspathElement>
          </additionalClasspathElements>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: or you can use `<classesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</classesDirectory>`

Answer (score 3):

I've faced this issue while migrating the Spring Boot project to JDK 17. In the end, the `failsafe` section of the `pom.xml` looked like this:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>integration-test</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>integration-test</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>verify</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>verify</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <forkCount>1</forkCount>
      <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
      <argLine>@{argLine}</argLine>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*IT.java</include>
      </includes>
      <classesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</classesDirectory>
      <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Adding classesDirectory solves my problem