# IntelliJ - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/jodah/failsafe/Policy

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, noclassdeffounderror

Please Help! I'm very vanilla when it comes to automation and all things Java/Code related.

If you respond, please remember that I am VERY new to all of this. Thank you

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/jodah/failsafe/Policy

```
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ClientConfig.<clinit>(ClientConfig.java:33)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:95)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:85)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.<init>(DriverCommandExecutor.java:80)
at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriverCommandExecutor.<init>(ChromiumDriverCommandExecutor.java:35)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver$ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:118)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:106)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:93)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:48)
at AssertionsExample2.setup(AssertionsExample2.java:18)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:168)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.jodah.failsafe.Policy
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
... 35 more

Part of my code:

public final class AssertionsExample2 {

```
WebDriver driver;

@BeforeClass
void setup()
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/tlwri/IdeaProjects/sampleJavaProject/Drivers/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
    driver=new ChromeDriver();
}
@Test (priority = 1)
void logoTest()
{
    WebElement logo=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"divLogo\"]/img"));
    Assert.assertTrue(logo.isDisplayed(),"Logo is not displayed on the page");
}
```

Comment: Try these links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50787704/maven-failsafe-fails-with-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror and this: https://www.baeldung.com/maven-failsafe-plugin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes and what are the differences between NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-causes-and-what-are-the-differences-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classn)

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar error running Selenium in Intellij IDEA.
I fixed it by adding "selenium-java-[version]/lib" to global libraries in addition to the "selenium-java-[version]" folder under thMe odule Settings menu.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error, and it disappeared when I added all the jars from the selenium lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, that was fixed by downloading failsafe .jar (https://mavenlibs.com/jar/file/dev.failsafe/failsafe) and adding it to classpath

Comment: Terrible idea to download a dependency jar manually. Use a maven/gradle dependency to that jar: net.jodah:failsafe'