# Maven surefire plugin does not detect Junit5 tests

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit5

I have already looked at 
[Surefire is not picking up Junit 5 tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36970384/surefire-is-not-picking-up-junit-5-tests)
and a few related questions however things are rapidly evolving with Junit5 that those suggestions don't seem to work anymore.

Maven : 3.3.9
I have the following in my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>23.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Only required to run tests in an IDE that bundles an older version -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Only required to run tests in an IDE that bundles an older version -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version>4.12.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

As you can see these are the most recent possible versions of Junit5 am guessing but when I run the mvn install command it still does not detect any tests.

Any suggestions? Pretty sure it is the maven + surefire plugin + Junit5 api + Junit5 engine not playing together and am happy to upgrade/downgrade versions to make it work.

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36970384/surefire-is-not-picking-up-junit-5-tests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could downgrade surefire to `v2.19`.

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/809) againt JUnit5 on Surefire 2.20.

The following Surefire configuration works with JUnit5:

```
<junit.platform.version>1.0.1</junit.platform.version>
<junit.jupiter.version>5.0.1</junit.jupiter.version>
<maven.surefire.plugin.version>2.19</maven.surefire.plugin.version>

<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Aaha so I had to use the dependencies inside the plugin section. I was just setting at the top level.