# Intellij does not run Junit5 tests

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, junit5, intellij-idea2017

This is a related question to [Maven surefire plugin does not detect Junit5 tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830325/maven-surefire-plugin-does-not-detect-junit5-tests) and I have read the [userguide](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-ide).

I have the following in my pom.xml and when I run the maven install the test gets run.

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <junit.platform.version>1.0.1</junit.platform.version>
    <junit.jupiter.version>5.0.2</junit.jupiter.version>
    <junit.vintage.version>4.12.2</junit.vintage.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>23.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Only required to run tests in an IDE that bundles an older version -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Only required to run tests in an IDE that bundles an older version -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.vintage.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

However when I run with Intellij IDEA 2017.1.5 the unit tests throw the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.launcher.Launcher.execute(Lorg/junit/platform/launcher/LauncherDiscoveryRequest;)V
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:61)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Unfortunately upgrading Intellij itself is going to take me slightly longer to achieve in an enterprise environment so is there any way to make this work in Intellij 2017.1.5 so that it runs the tests?

FYI the test I am attempting to run is NOT a vintage test it is a simple Junit5 test with the org.junit.jupiter.api.Test annotation

Comment: Found two platform versions: `<junit.platform.version>1.0.1</junit.platform.version>` and below a `<version>1.0.2</version>` -- but that should not be the issue.

Comment: Indeed I fixed it to be the same and I still have the same issue i.e, works when running mvn test but does not when running from Intellij

Answer (score 0):

## Update `surefire`

As I vaguely recall, there have been significant updates to `surefire` in the past 2-3 years. Try updating your [`maven-surefire-plugin`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin), currently at 3.0.0-M3.

## New `junit-jupiter` artifact

Note that as of 5.4.0 of JUnit, we can specify the new and very convenient single Maven artifact of [`junit-jupiter`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter) which in turn will supply 8 libraries to your project.

## Simplify your POM

You can drastically simplify your POM. Here is an example POM taken from the `maven-archetype-quickstart` version 1.4 archetype, though I have updated all the version numbers as of 2019-01.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>work.basil.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>acmeapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>acmeapp</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0-RC1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Tip: If you want to use JUnit assertions outside of test-related classes, in your regular app classes, drop the `<scope>test</scope>` element.

## Example class test

```
package work.basil.example;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

/**
 * Unit test for simple App.
 */
public class AppTest 
{
    /**
     * Rigorous Test :-)
     */
    @Test
    public void shouldAnswerWithTrue()
    {
        assertTrue( true );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the following dependencies with Gradle 5.0:

```
testCompile('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.0')
testCompile('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.4.0')
testCompile('org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.4.0')
testRuntime('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.4.0')
```