# Migration from Junit 4 to Junit 5 - Test case are getting skipped

Tags: java, maven, junit4, maven-surefire-plugin, junit5

I have migrated my junit 4 code to junit 5 with the below version dependencies.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

One of my scripts uses the command

```
mvn -B verify -DforkCount=1 -DreuseForks=false
```

But the issue I am facing is after migrating to junit5 while running it skips the testcase.

I am using `maven-surefire-plugin -  version 2.22.0.`

While running it just print the below line

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

I even tried the below configurations but no help

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <properties>
                <configurationParameters>
                    junit.jupiter.conditions.deactivate = *
                    junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled = true
                    junit.jupiter.testinstance.lifecycle.default = per_class
                    junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true
                </configurationParameters>
            </properties>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

My maven version is `3.3.9`

and does not run the test case. Any specific reason why I am facing this strange issue. The same test case with JUnit 4 earlier worked fine.

After further analysis what I found the command => `mvn -B verify -DforkCount=1 -DreuseForks=false` does not run the test case and skips them. But when i replace the same command with => `mvn -B verify -DforkCount=1 -DreuseForks=true` , it starts working. I understand that properties forkCount=1/reuseForks=true, which means that maven-surefire-plugin creates one new JVM process to execute all tests in one Maven module but want to know why it does not work with `mvn -B verify -DforkCount=1 -DreuseForks=false` command. Is any maven or maven helper version upgrade is required for Junit5 migration?

Comment: Which are the test's names? There is a name convention for tests, maybe could be that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Surefire is not picking up Junit 5 tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36970384/surefire-is-not-picking-up-junit-5-tests)

Comment: mvn -B verify -DforkCount=1 -DreuseForks=true  works but mvn -B verify -DforkCount=1 -DreuseForks=false does not. Just wanted to understand any specific reason for the same.

Comment: @melanzane it's not a duplicate. It's a different specific issue - see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52832399/2422776).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1566) in `maven-surefire-plugin` with JUnit 5.3[.1] and a configuration that uses forks but does not reuse them.

Upgrading to `maven-surefire-plugin` 2.22.1 (released last weekend, October 7th 2018) will solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Mureinik for the answer.It resolved my issue. You saved my day. Also thanks everyone for their responses.