# Maven silently fails to find JUnit tests to run

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

I've got a new Java project open in IntelliJ with Maven as its build tool, with one class and one JUnit 5 test class at the moment.  When I direct IntelliJ to run tests, individually or all together, it works.  But when I go to the terminal and hit `mvn clean test` or do the same from the Maven pane within IntelliJ, it skips over the tests.

Unlike [the questioner with this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178583/maven-does-not-find-junit-tests-to-run), however, I'm not getting any error message.  The test class *is* found and *does* compile.  I do not have the same problem (incorrect file naming) that he had.

EDIT: Stackoverflow asks me why this isn't a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36970384/surefire-is-not-picking-up-junit-5-tests).  It *is* the same problem, but their solution (from 2016) is no longer correct.  You don't need to add the "provider" dependency anymore.

Here's the relevant section of my Maven output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ markovmodels ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\joe\foo\markovmodels\target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ markovmodels ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\joe\foo\markovmodels\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.648 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-08-13T09:02:53-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I don't know if it's a useful clue, but I observed that the `target/surefire-reports` directory was not created.

In the `pom.xml` I have these two test-related dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

They are directly copied over from another project which works.  I have not specified a version of the Surefire plugin or changed any of its defaults, so the effective POM is the same as my other projects (it uses `maven-surefire-plugin` version 2.12.4).  The test source file seems to be in the right directory and have the right naming convention.  **What mistake could I be making?**

The code at its current state can be [here on Github](https://github.com/joeclark-phd/markovmodels/tree/639dd427656b581bda1f0e28ddb9f8c584a02936).

Comment: Use minimum maven-surefire-plugin 2.22.2 to things correctly working with JUnit Jupiter...

Comment: Does it work with junit 4.12 ? Do your test classes end with a `Test` ?

Comment: It wouldn't work with junit 4 because I use some of the new methods such as `assertThrows`.  The test class ends with a `@Nested` class containing tests.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Surefire is not picking up Junit 5 tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36970384/surefire-is-not-picking-up-junit-5-tests)

Comment: Lesiak and khmarbaise you both pointed me in the right direction.  I needed to specify a version of the maven-surefire-plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## It was an issue with the `maven-surefire-plugin`

There was something wrong with the default version of the `maven-surefire-plugin`, and I was able to fix it by upgrading that.  I solved the problem by copying relevant sections from the [JUnit5 sample Maven project on Github](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/r5.5.1/junit5-jupiter-starter-maven):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Using this same declaration for `junit-jupiter` and `maven-surefire-plugin` still does not work when declaring `spring-boot-starter-parent` as `<parent>`

Comment: @manasouza Try adding the `spring-boot-starter-test` dependency as well.  I have the two declarations above in one of my Spring Boot projects (plus a few other Spring Boot starters including `spring-boot-starter-test`) and it works.  For now, anyway.

Comment: This is the project, if you want to try to replicate it: https://github.com/joeclark-phd/granite