# running test suite is not working in junit5 through maven

Tags: junit5

@SelectPackages and @SelectClasses tags are not getting parsed with maven test command.Though it is working fine in IDE. Even I tried with  tag inside pom.xml.

Here is the code snippet :

---

### PaymentServiceTest.java

```
package xyz.howtoprogram.junit5.payment;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
public class PaymentServiceTest {
  @Test
  public void doPaymentZeroAmount() {
    assertEquals(1, 1);
  }
}
```

---

### UserFeatureSuiteTest.java

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@SelectPackages("xyz.howtoprogram.junit5.payment")
public class UserFeatureSuiteTest {
}
```

It is not running any of the test cases under the package. Though there is one test case underneath it.

xyz.howtoprogram.junit5.payment
   -> PaymentServiceTest.java

```
Running xyz.howtoprogram.junit5.suite.UserFeatureSuiteTest
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec - in xyz.howtoprogram.junit5.suite.UserFeatureSuiteTest.
```

Even I tried with changing the pom.xml like adding the 'include' tag.

---

### pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <junit.jupiter.version>5.0.0-M2</junit.jupiter.version>
    <junit.vintage.version>4.12.0-M2</junit.vintage.version>
    <junit.platform.version>1.0.0-M2</junit.platform.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/UserFeatureSuiteTest.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>${junit.vintage.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is the final POM,it is working now.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.howtoprogram</groupId>
<artifactId>junit5-test-suite-example</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>


<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <junit.jupiter.version>5.0.0-M2</junit.jupiter.version>
    <junit.vintage.version>4.12.0-M2</junit.vintage.version>
    <junit.platform.version>1.0.0-M2</junit.platform.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*SuiteTest.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

so the output is :

```
     T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Feb 23, 2017 10:21:06 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.ServiceLoaderTestEngineRegistry loadTestEngines
INFO: Discovered TestEngines with IDs: [junit-jupiter]
Running xyz.howtoprogram.junit5.suite.UserFeatureSuiteTest
Feb 23, 2017 10:21:06 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.ServiceLoaderTestEngineRegistry loadTestEngines
INFO: Discovered TestEngines with IDs: [junit-jupiter]
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.053 sec - in xyz.howtoprogram.junit5.suite.UserFeatureSuiteTest
```

Comment: It seems that there are problems with plugin dependencies because removing them helped me too.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for the confusion ... I just took a closer look at your code and realized you're trying to mix two concepts.

Your test code is annotated with the JUnit 5 @Test.  Therefore this code must be run with the junit-jupiter-engine.  That engine does **NOT** support declarative suites but does read in the configuration from the maven-surefire-plugin.

@RunWith is a JUnit4 annotation and is completely ignored within the junit-jupiter-engine.  I don't think it will cause the test to fail but it also will not enable any JUnit 5 tests.  The @SelectPackages annotation you've placed on your suite's class will, in this context, only help decide which JUnit 4 tests are run - but you don't have any.

Comment: I just re-edited the original pom.xml. I have added the surefire dependency to vintage and jupiter ( either one of them or both); It is not working in all cases. You could try out a simple program.

Comment: @SankarsanPadhy - no, I'm definitely not going to help you build a tutorial for an "answers site" like http://how-to-program.xyz/.  If you want to give expert advice, you need to spend the time to become an expert.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am trying to implement junit5 feature in our project. So, I looked around for the documents and example sites to try out them; but stumbled upon this issue. So, desperately seeking an help. I cannot just post my company code here. So posted the example I am trying in my local system.

Comment: @SankarsanPadhy - I'd like to apologize for being so critical ... I made some bad assumptions based on your samples above and shouldn't have dismissed your question out-of-hand.

Comment: no issues @steve-moyer. I tried and just figured out the solution.Kindly see my latest post.

Comment: I removed the \@RunWith and kept just the \@SelectPackages(...) and that works.  Many of the jUnit5 tutorials mistakenly recommend using @RunWith for a testing suite which is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

`@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)` is not supported when running tests via the JUnit Platform. If the new provider would pickup both `UserFeatureSuiteTest` and `PaymentServiceTest` your tests would be executed twice.

From the [User Guide](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-junit-platform-runner):

> Annotating a class with `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)` allows it to be run with IDEs and build systems that support JUnit 4 but do not yet support the JUnit Platform directly.

Thus, if you want `UserFeatureSuiteTest` to be run by Maven Surefire, you can use the "old" JUnit 4 support that is detected by default, i.e. just remove `junit-platform-surefire-provider` from the plug-in's dependencies.

Alternatively, you can directly execute your tests, e.g. `PaymentServiceTest`, through the JUnit Platform with your existing configuration.

Comment: No, unfortunately, it is not working even after removing the surefire-provider.

Comment: What about projects with both Jupiter and Vintage tests?

Comment: Nope, `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)` can only be used with JUnit 4.

Answer (score 1):

By default Maven uses the following naming conventions when looking for tests to run:

- `Test*`
- `*Test`
- `*TestCase`

Your test class doesn't follow these conventions. You should rename it or [configure Maven Surefire Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes) to use another pattern for test classes.

Another thing that could lead to your Maven to not work is that all the tests are supposed to be in the following folder:

> /my_application/src/test/java/MyFirstExampleTest.java

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178583/maven-does-not-find-junit-tests-to-run) you can see a quite good question for a generalization of your problem, from where I took some parts of my answer. You should take a look at it.

#### EDIT

Here you can see an example that explain how your pom.xml should be:

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.codefx.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-5</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-M3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-parameters</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0-M3</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <!-- contains the engine that actually runs the Jupiter-tests -->
                        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>5.0.0-M3</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

> As you can see in this configuration file you specify:
>
> - Dependency: you need a test scoped dependency of JUnit in order to run tests
> - In the build section you will add the surefire plugin that will run your tests along with its dependencies

Comment: It did not help. So, I have re-edited the original issue with detailed steps.

Comment: @SankarsanPadhy edited my answer explaining you how your pom should be. I think that this may be your problem

Comment: not working. I have reedited the original issue with the complete pom.xml

Comment: @SankarsanPadhy Did you try to refactor the name of your test class from TestPaymentService.java to PaymentServiceTest.java. I was looking into http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/ and I think that, the suits is going to recognize only class that match with this ^.*Tests?$

Comment: I refactored it, did not update the original issue. it is not working. I would strongly request you to run a small program yourself. I tried with several trial and error but could not succeed till yet.

Comment: This answer helped me. Thanks