# Maven skips test files and runs non-test file instead

Tags: java, maven, junit

I converted my eclipse project into a maven project. I have following files in the test part of the project:

[image]

The `TestException` is an `Exception` class that us used in cases where exception should be thrown (it makes sense in this project). `MultiResults` and `TestSyncPromise` are the actual classes containing JUnit tests.

When select `Run as -> 9 Maven test` I get the following output:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.811 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-10T20:04:45+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/197M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I instead select `Run as -> JUnit test`, the correct files are interpreted as tests.

This is what I've put into my `pom.xml`:

```
  <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
      <junit.jupiter.version>5.0.0-M4</junit.jupiter.version>
      <junit.platform.version>1.0.0-M4</junit.platform.version>
  </properties>


  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

How do I tell Maven which files are tests and which are just utility classes?

Comment: The behaviour is due to maven's naming convention for unit tests. Please check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6178629/4897413

Comment: @gjoranv Then why is `TestSyncPromise` not ran?

Comment: First I would suggest to follow the convention over configuration paradigm and remove the configuration for sourceDirectory and testSourceDirectory...apart from that I would ask why are using such old version of junit-jupiter platform? Most recent 5.3.1? Another thing is which version of maven-surefire-plugin do you use? Have you checked on plain command line first?

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for your suggestions, but none of them had any effect. I updated my question after fixing the paths in `pom.xml`, but surely you noticed that Maven is picking the right folder, so there's no surprise that it still does not work.