# Maven is not running any test

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, junit

I am writing the unit test for the first time. In order to create the test file in IntelliJ, I created a `*Test.java` by using shortcut [https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/create-tests.html]. Now when I am trying to run `mvn test` it is not running any tests.

pom.xml

```
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
          <version>5.6.2</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
```

1. Few answers from SO I found was to check the name. I checked and the name of the file is `<classNametoTest>Test.java` and I can also see the JUnit symbol on the file.
2. I have another folder named `test` (in root directory). In order to verify, I tried to rename the folder and did `mvn clean package` -> `mvn test`. Not tests run.
3. `Test` folder is there in `src` as well [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178583/maven-does-not-find-junit-tests-to-run]

Comment: Have you configured the surefire plugin? https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html

Comment: Please add your full pom file...

Comment: I imported @test from org.junit.jupiter.api.Test and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you check if you have `@Test` is imported from `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`