# Jacoco not considering coverage for all test classes

Tags: java, maven, jacoco

I have jacoco running for my build and I noticed if there's 2 test classes testing the same main class, coverage from one of the test classes is missing.
For example, I have a class MyApp. Now I have MyAppTest and MyAppLatestTest. In this case only coverage from MyAppTest is considered. Has anyone faced this problem? Is there a potential solution to this?

Comment: I have 2 classes with the same name in 2 different module, and jhave written test classes for each of them in their respective module.
BUt the second class is not being considered in the report.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a shortcoming of maven surefire rather than jacoco. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6178629/3402233