JaCoCo abstract class test coverage
I have an abstract class which contains some methods that are shared by the classes that inherit the methods. In general this abstract class filters request parameters by requests, afterwards they are handled by the concrete implementation. Let's say the abstract class contains a method that looks like this:
public class HandlerAbstract {

    protected String getUserName(NativeWebRequest request, @Valid RequestBodyOptions requestBodyOptions) throws HandlerException {
        String requestBodyOptionsUserName = null;
        String requestParameterUserName = request.getParameter("username");

        if (requestBodyOptions != null) {
            requestBodyOptionsUserName = requestBodyOptions.getUserName();
        }

        if (requestBodyOptionsUserName != null && requestParameterUserName == null) {
            return requestBodyOptionsUserName;
        } else if (requestBodyOptionsUserName == null && requestParameterUserName != null) {
            return requestParameterUserName;
        } else if (requestBodyOptionsUserName != null && requestParameterUserName != null && !(requestBodyOptionsUserName.equals(requestBodyOptionsUserName))) {
            throw new HandlerException("The username passed in the request body and the request parameters are not the same.");
        } else if (requestBodyOptionsUserName != null && requestParameterUserName != null && requestBodyOptionsUserName.equals(requestBodyOptionsUserName)) {
            return requestBodyOptionsUserName;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }

}

I have the following tests:
@Test
public void testUserNameBody(){
    HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();

    NativeWebRequest mockRequest = getNativeWebRequest(parameters);

    RequestBodyOptions requestBodyOptions = new RequestBodyOptions();
    requestBodyOptions.setUserName("user-name");

    HandlerAbstract handlerImplementation = new HandlerImplementation();

    String userName = handlerImplementation.getUserName(mockRequest, options);

    Assertions.assertEquals("user-name", userName);
}

@Test
public void testUserNameRequestParameter(){
    HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("username", "user-name");

    NativeWebRequest mockRequest = getNativeWebRequest(parameters);

    RequestBodyOptions requestBodyOptions = new RequestBodyOptions();

    HandlerAbstract handlerImplementation = new HandlerImplementation();

    String userName = handlerImplementation.getUserName(mockRequest, options);

    Assertions.assertEquals("user-name", userName);
}


@Test
public void testUserName2DifferentValues(){
    HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("username", "user-name");

    NativeWebRequest mockRequest = getNativeWebRequest(parameters);

    RequestBodyOptions requestBodyOptions = new RequestBodyOptions();
    requestBodyOptions.setUserName("somethingelse");

    try{
        HandlerAbstract handlerImplementation = new HandlerImplementation();
        String tokenSecret = handlerImplementation.getUserName(mockRequest, options);
        Assertions.fail("Should have thrown an exception but did not throw any exception");
    }catch (HandlerException e){
        Assertions.assertEquals("The username passed in the request body and the request parameters are not the same.", e.getMessage());
    }catch (Exception e){
        Assertions.fail("Should have thrown a HandlerException but threw: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Test
public void testUserNameEqualValues(){
    HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("username", "user-name");

    NativeWebRequest mockRequest = getNativeWebRequest(parameters);

    RequestBodyOptions requestBodyOptions = new RequestBodyOptions();
    requestBodyOptions.setUserName("user-name");

    HandlerAbstract handlerImplementation = new HandlerImplementation();

    String userName = handlerImplementation.getUserName(mockRequest, options);

    Assertions.assertEquals("user-name", userName);
}

The problem is that when I run the tests and I check the code coverage report with jacoco, jacoco tells me that only the point of the method where the exception occurred is covered by tests. All the other return statements are marked as not covered.
If I add a log or an exception to the different points where it is supposed to return the value, it gets thrown/logged while running the tests. Idem if I run it with Intelij code coverage. If I run these tests with debug, all the lines get covered.
At first, I thought it was because of using mockito but so I created the NativeWebRequest like this but it doesn't resolve it:
    private NativeWebRequest getNativeWebRequest(HashMap<String, String> parameters){
        MockHttpServletRequest httpRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest();

        // Add parameters to the request
        parameters.forEach((key, value) -> {
            httpRequest.addParameter(key, value);
        });

        NativeWebRequest nativeWebRequest = new ServletWebRequest(httpRequest);

        return nativeWebRequest;
    }


Then I have tried to explicitly set the request parameter to null in the request, or in the request body options, but also that didn't resolve it.
I have created a new concrete implementation of the abstract class in the test, since I thought that maybe that is where Jacoco got confused, but also that didn't resolve it.
I have double checked whether my surefire plugin is set up properly and it is. The tests that I want to use for improving test coverage are run (https://stackoverflow.com/a/67220369/12171869)
I am working in a multi-module project with a module for integration tests. I have excluded the integration test coverage from the jacoco report generation, in the assumption that the aggregated report generation was causing the issue. However, the method remains not fully covered.

Long story short: I want to get to full test coverage, but I seem to do it improperly, causing Jacoco to think that the method is not fully covered.

I think you left out the part of the question where you say what problem you're experiencing; it jumps straight from context (which makes sense) to your debugging attempts (which also make sense, I think, though it's hard to be sure without knowing what the problem is). Can you edit that in?

Thank you @ruakh for the response. I edited the question.

I attempted to reproduce the issue, and I couldn't; JaCoCo correctly identified the covered code for me. However, I had to make a bunch of changes to your code to work in my setup (e.g. because your code refers to random classes I don't recognize), and it's possible that some of those changes are relevant. Can you create a minimal, reproducible example?

(Actually, come to think of it, the code that you've posted can't possibly work in your setup, either: there are some variable-name mismatches, and also, the code has a bug that means that the HandlerException path is never reached.)
