# SpringBoot - Create empty test class for demo

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

How can I create a empty test class that if `mvn test` is run it should return `Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0`? Right now without any tests `mvn` reports `no tests to run`. I'm working on a demo jenkins pipeline and the script expects all projects to return `Tests run: 0 or more`.

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.4.2:test (default-test) @ demo-web ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.535 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-09-27T09:04:22Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Pipeline] script
```

[image]

I  tried to create a test class but it returns 1 test result. I want zero test results.

`BanksMvcControllerTest.java`

```
package com.WebDemo.Controller;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;

import com.webDemo.WebApplication;

import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = WebApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class BanksMvcControllerTest {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

Comment: afaik you cannot. You either have 1 test that runs or 1 that is ignored. So no you cannot have all the counters set to 0.

Comment: oh okay. I was expecting something like this from the asnwer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69334020/13410618

Comment: Nope. So either write a test, or skip it, but it will lead to output with a 1 at one place. If there is nothing you get the message you get now (not sure if that is configurable). But why not just put in that single test and it will adhere to the rules of your CI...

Answer (score 1):

You could probably annotate the test with `@Ignore` (for JUnit 4) or `@Disabled` (for JUnit 5)

Comment: I get the errror `java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods` when trying `@ignore`. Can you please show the code as to how to ignore?

Comment: @John hmm I thought that would work, but it seems you need a minimum of 1 test to actually NOT be ignored if you use that.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code:

```
@Ignore
@Test
public void contextLoads() {
}
```

Or:

```
@Ignore
public class BanksMvcControllerTest
```

Comment: Tired that. I get the errror java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods

Comment: Can you remove that public before class ? or make it abstract

Comment: I get the following error `java.lang.Exception: Method contextLoads() should be public`

Comment: @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) try this also it should work