# Test cases are not running when doing a mvn clean install but the project is compiling success

Tags: java, maven, junit4, junit5, openjdk-11

But when I am running the individual test case by right click and run as junit test, they are executing successfully. I am using junit 4. Just to update that I have explicitly created package under src/test/java and deleted the default test class that used to come by default when creating a maven project.
Is there any place to specify the test package in pom?
Below is the pom file:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>     <!-- NOT org.junit here -->
            <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20171018</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
            <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId> 
            </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.18.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-freemarker -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <from>
                        <image>openjdk:11.0.9.1-jdk</image>
                    </from>
                    <to>
                        <image>${docker.registry.baseurl}/${project.artifactId}:${docker.tag}</image>
                    </to>
                    <container>
                        <creationTime>USE_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP</creationTime>
                    </container>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And the test case is :

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MyControllerTest {

    @Mock
    MyService myService;
    @InjectMocks
    private MyController myController;

    @Test
    public void testPostData() {
        when(myService.postLRAData()).thenReturn(" Data saved to DB successfully!!");
        ResponseEntity<String> response = new ResponseEntity<String>("Data saved to DB successfully!!",
                HttpStatus.CREATED);
        assertEquals(response, myController.postLRAData());
    }

}
```

And the project structure is :
[project dir structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EGta.png)

Comment: `mvn clean test`?

Comment: Run now is handled by the IDE, so something is wrong in your maven setup. Can you run the above command with `-X` for debug. That might reveal a problem. Otherwise try to search SO for surefire+junit4. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021771/surefire-is-not-picking-up-junit-4-tests

Comment: @JoopEggen tried with mvn clean test, it is also showing the same thing:
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Comment: The test sources are under src/test/java/? (Not src/main/java/.)

Comment: @JoopEggen, it is inside src/test/java only

Comment: I see `" Data...` with space and without space `"Data...` - but there it does not arrive at.

Comment: @JoopEggen, that should not make much difference but my point is test case should execute atleast

Answer (score 0):

Test cases are successfully running when `mvn clean install`

then required one plugin in `pom.xml`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <configuration>
        <test>**</test>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

`** -> qualified name of test class with extension .java`

for example:

```
package com.test;

import org.junit.Test;
public class Check {

    @Test
    public void test() {
    
        //test cases logic
    }
}
```

`like : com.test.Check.java`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <configuration>
        <test>com.test.Check.java</test>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

After that run `mvn clean install`